# JavaScript inheritance and the constructor property

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, instanceof

Consider the following code.

```
function a() {}
function b() {}
function c() {}

b.prototype = new a();
c.prototype = new b();

console.log((new a()).constructor); //a()
console.log((new b()).constructor); //a()
console.log((new c()).constructor); //a()
```

- Why isn't the constructor updated for b and c?
- Am I doing inheritance wrong?
- What is the best way to update the constructor?

Further, please consider the following.

```
console.log(new a() instanceof a); //true
console.log(new b() instanceof b); //true
console.log(new c() instanceof c); //true
```

- Given that `(new c()).constructor` is equal to `a()` and `Object.getPrototypeOf(new c())` is `a{ }`, how is it possible for `instanceof` to know that `new c()` is an instance of `c`?

> http://jsfiddle.net/ezZr5/

Comment: Any reason why you need the constructor to be updated? I find my life is easier if I just pretend that property doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm having a hard time closing this as a duplicate - all the other questinos are so verbose...

Comment: `c.prototype` is `b()` and `b.prototype` is `a()`, therefore `c.prototype` is `a()`

Comment: @pimvdb is right, you need to manually set the constructor. For the sake of posterity - here's a fiddle based on the Pseudo Classical Inheritance pattern from Stoyan Stefanovs "Javacript Patterns": http://jsfiddle.net/sunwukung/YXxG6/

Comment: That's an helpful fiddle, but your `Child.hasOwnProperty('name')` is a little ambiguous - it returns `true` because functions always have a `.name` property (in this case, `"Child"`). I'm not sure if that's what you meant (it is not the `name` that `Parent` sets, because the constructor does not have that property set by it).

Comment: lol, good spot! In fact, that line should evaluate false - since the property is inherited. I learnt something too today!!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Okay, let's play a little mind game:

[image]

From the above image we can see:

1. When we create a function like `function Foo() {}`, JavaScript creates a `Function` instance.
2. Every `Function` instance (the constructor function) has a property `prototype` which is a pointer.
3. The `prototype` property of the constructor function points to its prototype object.
4. The prototype object has a property `constructor` which is also a pointer.
5. The `constructor` property of the prototype object points back to its constructor function.
6. When we create a new instance of `Foo` like `new Foo()`, JavaScript creates a new object.
7. The internal `[[proto]]` property of the instance points to the prototype of the constructor.

Now, the question arises that why doesn't JavaScript attach the `constructor` property to the instance object instead of the prototype. Consider:

```
function defclass(prototype) {
    var constructor = prototype.constructor;
    constructor.prototype = prototype;
    return constructor;
}

var Square = defclass({
    constructor: function (side) {
        this.side = side;
    },
    area: function () {
        return this.side * this.side;
    }
});

var square = new Square(10);

alert(square.area()); // 100
```

As you can see the `constructor` property is just another method of the prototype, like `area` in the example above. What makes the `constructor` property special is that it's used to initialize an instance of the prototype. Otherwise it's exactly the same as any other method of the prototype.

Defining the `constructor` property on the prototype is advantageous for the following reasons:

1. It's logically correct. For example consider `Object.prototype`. The `constructor` property of `Object.prototype` points to `Object`. If the `constructor` property was defined on the instance then `Object.prototype.constructor` would be `undefined` because `Object.prototype` is an instance of `null`.
2. It's treated no differently from other prototype methods. This makes the job of `new` easier since it doesn't need to define the `constructor` property on every instance.
3. Every instance shares the same `constructor` property. Hence it's efficient.

Now when we talk about inheritance, we have the following scenario:

[image]

From the above image we can see:

1. The derived constructor's `prototype` property is set to the instance of the base constructor.
2. Hence the internal `[[proto]]` property of the instance of the derived constructor points to it too.
3. Thus the `constructor` property of the derived constructor instance now points to the base constructor.

As for the `instanceof` operator, contrary to popular belief it doesn't depend on the `constructor` property of the instance. As we can see from above, that would lead to erroneous results.

The `instanceof` operator is a binary operator (it has two operands). It operates on an instance object and a constructor function. As explain on [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#Determining_instance_relationships), it simply does the following:

```
function instanceOf(object, constructor) {
    while (object != null) {
        if (object == constructor.prototype) { //object is instanceof constructor
            return true;
        } else if (typeof object == 'xml') { //workaround for XML objects
            return constructor.prototype == XML.prototype;
        }
        object = object.__proto__; //traverse the prototype chain
    }
    return false; //object is not instanceof constructor
}
```

To put it simply if `Foo` inherits from `Bar`, then the prototype chain for the instance of `Foo` would be:

1. `foo.__proto__ === Foo.prototype`
2. `foo.__proto__.__proto__ === Bar.prototype`
3. `foo.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype`
4. `foo.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ === null`

As you can see, every object inherits from the `Object` constructor. The prototype chain ends when an internal `[[proto]]` property points to `null`.

The `instanceof` function simply traverses the prototype chain of the instance object (the first operand) and compares the internal `[[proto]]` property of each object to the `prototype` property of the constructor function (the second operand). If they match, it returns `true`; and else if the prototype chain ends, it returns `false`.

Comment: +1 I'd prefer `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead of `.__proto__` though.

Comment: I only used the `__proto__` property for the sake of explanation. That's the way it was explained on Mozilla Developer Network. Nevertheless, the `__proto__` property does have an advantage over the `Object.getPrototypeOf` method in than it's faster (no function call overhead) and that it's implemented by all the major browsers. The only reason I would use `Object.getPrototypeOf` is to work around implementations like Rhino which do not support the `__proto__` property. We all have our own preferences. I prefer the `__proto__` property because it's more readable. Cheers. =)

Comment: 2 questions -  1. Is the base constructor always Object? I'm having a hard time proving that in code. :( It always points to first constructor after Object. 2. When we chain __proto__, we are dereferencing the original prototype objects. Does that me we will not receive any of the properties from the those prototype objects except the Object prototype? After all prototypes are attached not added to instances.

Comment: @CodeHater Why would the arrows point in the opposite direction?

Answer (score 12):

By default,

```
function b() {}
```

then `b.prototype` has a `.constructor` property which is set to `b` automatically. However, you're currently overwriting the prototype and thus discarding that variable:

```
b.prototype = new a;
```

Then `b.prototype` does not have a `.constructor` property anymore; it was erased with the overwrite. It *does* inherit from `a` though,  and `(new a).constructor === a`, and hence `(new b).constructor === a` (it is referring to the same property in the prototype chain).

Best to do is to simply setting it manually afterwards:

```
b.prototype.constructor = b;
```

You could also make a little function for this:

```
function inherit(what, from) {
    what.prototype = new from;
    what.prototype.constructor = what;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/79xTg/5/

Comment: That's all true. But then you wouldn't know that a certain object is *inherited*. `new b() instanceof a` returns `false` when you use `$.extend` which may be undesired in OP's case if he needs to check inheritance.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: Good point, but `b instanceof b` is always false since the constructor is not an instance of itself. The extend function does seem to work for `new b instanceof b`, unless I'm misunderstaning you: http://jsfiddle.net/79xTg/3/.

Comment: I edited my comment. It was of course a typo. And let me edit your example: http://jsfiddle.net/79xTg/4/ `$.extend` doesn't do inheritance but rather `prototype` copy. Hence you can't check inheritance using it.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: You're correct. Since extend is not made for inheritance purposes I removed it.

Answer (score 6):

`constructor` is a regular, non-enumerable property of the default value of the `prototype` property of function objects. Thus, assigning to `prototype` will lose the property.

`instanceof` will still work as it does not use `constructor`, but rather scans the prototype chain of the object for the (current) value of the function's `prototype` property, ie `foo instanceof Foo` is equivalent to

```
var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(foo);
for(; proto !== null; proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto)) {
    if(proto === Foo.prototype)
        return true;
}
return false;
```

In ECMAScript3, there's no way to set a `constructor` property which behaves identically to the built-in one as user-defined properties are always enumerable (ie visible to `for..in`).

This changed with ECMAScript5. However, even if you set `constructor` manually, your code still has issues: In particular, it is a bad idea to set `prototype` to an instance of the parent-'class' - the parent constructor should not be called when the child-'class' is defined, but rather when child-instances are created.

Here's some ECMAScript5 example code for how it should be done:

```
function Pet(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Pet.prototype.feed = function(food) {
    return this.name + ' ate ' + food + '.';
};

function Cat(name) {
    Pet.call(this, name);
}

Cat.prototype = Object.create(Pet.prototype, {
    constructor : {
        value : Cat,
        writable : true,
        enumerable : false,
        configurable : true
    }
});

Cat.prototype.caress = function() {
    return this.name + ' purrs.';
};
```

If you're stuck with ECMAScript3, you'll need to use a custom [`clone()` function](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/js-hacks/raw-file/tip/clone.js) instead of `Object.create()` and won't be able to make `constructor` non-enumerable:

```
Cat.prototype = clone(Pet.prototype);
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;
```