# How to set class name for JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, instanceof, ecmascript-5

I have some test class

```
TestKlass = (function() {

    function TestKlass(value) {
      this.value = value != null ? value : 'hello world';
      console.log(this.value);
    }

    return TestKlass;

})();

x = new TestKlass;
x instanceof TestKlass; (gives true)
```

I have new empty object

```
y = {}
y instanceof Object
```

Can I find any ways to set any properties for **y**, something like this

```
y.__proto__ = x.__proto__
y.constructor.prototype = x.constructor.prototype
```

for to have this result

```
y instanceof TestKlass => true
```

====================================================

**UPD:**

So. My main aim - it's to create CLONE function. Now my solution works for me. Please look at this code:

JavaScript JS object clone

```
Object._clone = function(obj) {
  var clone, property, value;
  if (!obj || typeof obj !== 'object') {
    return obj;
  }
  clone = typeof obj.pop === 'function' ? [] : {};
  clone.__proto__ = obj.__proto__;
  for (property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      value = obj.property;
      if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
        clone[property] = Object._clone(value);
      } else {
        clone[property] = obj[property];
      }
    }
  }
  return clone;
};
```

CoffeeScript JS object clone

```
# Object clone
Object._clone = (obj) ->
  return obj if not obj or typeof(obj) isnt 'object'
  clone = if typeof(obj.pop) is 'function' then [] else {}

  # deprecated, but need for instanceof method
  clone.__proto__ = obj.__proto__

  for property of obj
    if obj.hasOwnProperty property
      # clone properties
      value = obj.property
      if value and typeof(value) is 'object'
        clone[property] = Object._clone(value)
      else
        clone[property] = obj[property]

  clone
```

Now you can try to do that

```
A = new TestKlass
B = Object._clone(A)
B instanceof TestKlass => true
```

It's work fine with Moz FF 13. But I think it's not cross-browser. and **proto** is deprecated.

I think there is no universal solution. But maybe It's will be helpful for somebody.

Comment: `y.constructor = x.constructor`?  Just a guess... Really, though, you shouldn't be caring about types.  I mean, if there's an easy way to fake them, what good are they at all?

Comment: Do the answers provide you enough information? If so, could you kindly accept an answer? :-)

Comment: I am just looking for best solution. I will mark best answer after deep learn this page http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object/inheritance (russian)

Comment: answer of Aadit Shah is closer for me. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should read the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743) first. What you are trying to achieve is really simple. However before I explain let's look at your solutions:

**Solution 1**

```
y.__proto__ = x.__proto__;
```

I wouldn't recommend doing this as the `__proto__` property is now [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Proto). The above code won't work in [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/).

**Solution 2**

```
y.constructor.prototype = x.constructor.prototype;
```

This is a very bad solution. The reason is that `y.constructor` is actually `y.__proto__.constructor` and since `y` is an object `y.__proto__` is the same as `Object.prototype`. This means that `y.constructor` is the same as `Object` and you're essentially changing the `prototype` property of `Object`. This could potentially break other code on your page. I strongly discourage this practice.

**Solution 3 (my solution)**

What you want to do is simply change the internal `[[proto]]` property of an object. Since there's no cross platform way to do so we need to employ a hack. A simple solution would be to create a new object with the desired `__proto__` property and set getters and setters on it to change the original object. It would be as follows:

```
function setPrototypeOf(object, prototype) {
    var constructor = function () {
        for (var key in object) {
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                (function (key) {
                    Object.defineProperty(this, key, {
                        get: function () {
                            return object[key];
                        },
                        set: function (value) {
                            object[key] = value;
                        },
                        enumerable: true
                    });
                }).call(this, key);
            }
        }
    };

    constructor.prototype = prototype;

    return new constructor;
}
```

After this all you need to do is:

```
y = setPrototypeOf(y, TestKlass.prototype);
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnVGm/).

**Edit:**

The problem with your clone function is that it only clones objects and arrays. You forgot to account for functions which are also passed by reference. Thus when you clone an object which has methods which [close over](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)) the internal state of the object, the object and its clone will share the same internal state. See the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTdCN/):

```
function Value(value) {
    this.get = function () {
        alert(value);
    };
    this.set = function (newValue) {
        value = newValue;
    };
}

var a = new Value(5);
var b = Object._clone(a);
b.set(10);                // setting b to 10 also sets a to 10
a.get();                  // alerts 10, should alert 5
```

There's absolutely no way in JavaScript to clone the internal state of an object so cloning objects and arrays in JavaScript will only work for objects which do not expose closures as methods.

To know more about the problems with cloning objects in JavaScript read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/728694/783743). Click on the following [link](http://tinyurl.com/JSCopyObject) to read John Resig's answer.

Answer (score 1):

`obj instanceof SomeConstructor` checks whether SomeConstructor is found anywhere in the prototype chain of obj.

If you want inheritance, you need to set the .prototype of FirstConstructor to a newly created SomeConstructor object.

```
SomeConstructor = function() {}
FirstConstructor = function() {}
FirstConstroctor.prototype = new SomeConstructor();

var y = new FirstConstroctor();
y instanceof FirstConstructor; // true
y instanceof SomeConstructor ; // true, it bubbles from FirstConstructor.__proto__ to SomeConstructor
```