# Javascript component based game design

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I am developing a browser based game on a node.js server. I'm trying to implement a component based inheritance structure but I am unsure of the concepts with regards to javascript inheritance.

As far as I can make out, if I want to inherit from two component objects e.g. `function Moves(){}` and `function IsVisible(){}`, the usual prototypal inheritance doesn't work:

```
gameObject.prototype = new Moves;
gameObject.prototype = new IsVisible;
```

The is `IsVisible` object overwrites the `Moves` object as the `gameObject` prototype.

Below is my attempt at creating an inherit function that takes a target object and an arbitrary number of component objects as arguments. The target object then inherits the behavior and variables from the these components.

I'm not familiar with javascript inheritance and would like to know if the below method a good way of implementing a multiple inheritance type structure in javascript?

Are there any other well established practices dealing with this problem? (*If it is a problem...*)

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function inherit(o){

    var proto = o;
    for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
        var component =  new arguments[i]();
        for(var x in component){
            proto[x] = component[x];
        }
    }
}

function Player(name){

    var o = {};
    o.name = name;
    inherit(o, WorldSpace, Active);
    return o;

}

function WorldSpace(){
    this.pos = {x:0, y:0};
    this.orientation=0;
}

function Active(){
    this.acceleration = 1;
    this.velocity = {x:0,y:0};
    this.rotation = 0;
    this.rotationSpeed = (Math.PI*2)/30;
    this.throttle = false;
    this.currentSpeed = 0;
    this.maxSpeed = 10;
}
```

Comment: Try making Player a constructor, and use the traditional way of javascript inheritance as can be found all over the web.

Comment: @Bergi Javascript doesn't support multiple inheritance so using `person.prototype = new WorldSpace; person.prototype = new Active` wouldn't work.

Comment: You don't want multiple inheritance, you want only mixins - you have no prototypes in your code. AaditMShah is perfectly right.

Comment: @Bergi Your line is now my googlism: http://www.googlism.com/who_is/a/aaditmshah/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I see in your code you don't really need multiple inheritance. You are simply trying to mix in code from different constructors into one. This is possible and is actually really simple to achieve in JavaScript.

First let's rewrite your code for `Player`:

```
function Player(name) {
    this.name = name;
    WorldSpace.apply(this);
    Active.apply(this);
}
```

That's it. Simple right? Let me explain how the [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) function works:

1. Every function in JavaScript has a special pointer called `this`.
2. When you call a function normally `this` usually points to the global object (e.g. `window`).
3. When you call a function preceded by the keyword `new` JavaScript creates an instance of that function and `this` points to that instance.
4. JavaScript also has two functions `call` and `apply` which are methods of every function and allow you to call that function with any value for the `this` pointer.

So essentially when I call `WorldSpace.apply` with `this` as the first argument, the `this` pointer in the `WorldSpace` function points the `this` in `Player`. You are essentially using the `WorldSpace` and `Active` constructors as [mixins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin).

If you want to know more about how inheritance works in JavaScript I suggest you read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743). Have you considered using a [framework](https://github.com/javascript/augment) to make your life simpler?

Comment: Brilliant, I knew there must be a better way of doing it. I'm not considering a framework at the moment to concentrate on learning core javascript. Thanks for your help.