# How can I extend the document object?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm currently trying to get a better understanding of JavaScript and prototyping.

I wanted to add a function to the `document` but `prototype` is undefined on `document`.

This code:

```
document.prototype.writeLine = function(text){
    this.write(text);
    this.write("<br />");  
};
```

Generates this error:

```
// In FireFox
TypeError: document.prototype is undefined

// In Chrome
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'writeLine' of undefined
```

How can I extend the `document` object to be able to call something similar to `document.WriteLine('MyText')` ?

Here is the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qpZ6K/) I'm working with.

Comment: Since there's only one `document` on a page, you could just add the function directly: `document.writeLine = function(text) {...}` This way you don't need to worry about variations in the DOM implementation.

Comment: @user1689607: Wow, this works brilliantly in FF as well as Chrome. Nice. that makes sense, if there is only ever a single document object prototype would not be needed. I never though of that. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qpZ6K/4/). The problem you were having is that `document` object is an instance of the `HTMLDocument` object type. The *instance* itself doesn't have a prototype, however the `HTMLDocument` does.

**Update**: Here is a snippet which works in IE9 because under IE9 `HTMLDocument` is `undefined`.

```js
if (typeof HTMLDocument !== 'undefined') {
    HTMLDocument.prototype.writeLine = function(text){
        this.write(text);
        this.write("<br />");  
    };
} else {
    Document.prototype.writeLine = function(text){
        this.write(text);
        this.write("<br />");  
    };
}

document.writeLine("Line 1");
document.writeLine("Line 2");
```

Comment: Nice. Is there a reason though why `document.writeLine("Line 2");` creates error: `TypeError: document.writeLine is not a function`? However, the first call to `document.writeLine` works.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl what browser are you trying this under? It works for me nicely in webkit.

Comment: It only does that in FireFox. I will accept your answer as it solved my issue. that the second line fails to execute in FireFox seems to be specific to FF. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: As `user1689607` mentioned in the comment on the question, just using `document.writeLine` works as well. I never thought of `prototype` not being realy needed as only a single instance of `document' exists.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: It breaks in firefox because you're using `document.write` after the DOM is loaded, which wipes out the `document` element. [Here's an update](http://jsfiddle.net/qpZ6K/3/) that runs the code in the `head` instead of `onload`, so that the writing takes place while the document is still loading.

Comment: @user1689607: That's realy good information. I'm going to accept this answer as it has addressed my initial issue. You have not added an yourself but added valuable information on the question and this post. Thank you.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I updated with a new fiddle which works under IE9 as well.

Comment: @KonstantinD-Infragistics: Thankyou so much for the fiddles, I will be adding them to my fiddle dashboard for future references :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `document` is of type `object` and not `function`. In JavaScript you use functions as constructors like this:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.myProperty = "something";
}
```

You may create an instance of `MyClass` as follows:

```
var myInstance = new MyClass;
alert(myInstance.myProperty);
```

Every function also has a property called `prototype` which is an object. All the properties of the prototype are inherited my instances of the constructor function:

```
MyClass.prototype.displayProperty = function () {
    alert(this.myProperty);
};

myInstance.displayProperty();
```

In your case since `document` is the instance of a constructor and not the constructor itself, there's no property called `prototype` on it.

For more information about inheritance in JavaScript read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743).

Answer (score 1):

is very easy, document and Document are both different, document is the document of the window and Document is the interface of the document (thats comone from DOM), if your like add a new prototype for you use in your document you need add this but into Document like  this: 
**window.Document.prototype.Sayhi = "Hello World"**
or ***Document.prototype.Sayhi = "Hello World"***
and now you can call this from you document like
***document.sayhi***
thats happen because you need Set the prototype on Interfaces if you like for example add a new prototype in your Object window your need Set it at Window interface like:
Window.prototype.Saybye = "Bye Bro See You Later"
and you can call the prototype in you window.Saybye
remember, Window is an interface that contain window like Document and document****

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).