# How to create an instance of my own class, but make it behave like a Node

Tags: javascript, dom, prototype

**Edit: I'm closing this question as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489738/how-to-inherit-from-the-dom-element-class).**

I can't wrap my mind around this simple concept. I want to create a class, say:

```
function InputExt() {
    ...
}
```

And then I want to do something like this:

```
InputExt.prototype = document.createElement('input');
```

But this would only give my `InputExt` methods and properties of a `Node`, while `InputExt` instances will not behave as a `Node`, nor as a `HTMLInputElement`.

How can I achieve the behavior below?

```
InputExt.prototype.info = function() {
    console.log(this);
}
var element = document.body.appendChild(new InputExt());
element.info();
```

Comment: You need to extend the domObject I think
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689768/how-can-i-extend-the-document-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function InputExt() {
     var element = document.createElement('input');
     for (prop in InputExt.prototype) {
         element[prop] = InputExt.prototype[prop];
     }
     return element;
 }


 InputExt.prototype.info = function() {
     console.log(this);
 }


 var element = document.body.appendChild(new InputExt());
 element.info();
```

Comment: You rock. This is so simple! Extending the idea: in the `InputExt` definition something like `var self = document.createElement('input'); self.field = 'test'; return self;` can be used to emulate `this` like you would use it in regular class definitions.

Comment: Okay, there's one problem though. Every instance of `HTMLInputElement` now has an `.info()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, I think you need to extend a DOMElement, because that is was `document.body.appendChild` is creating.

More details [How can I extend the document object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689768/how-can-i-extend-the-document-object)

Here is an example of how this could look like

```
function InputExt(){}

InputExt.prototype.inputnode= document.createElement('input')

InputExt.prototype.info = function(domInfo) {
  console.log(this.inputnode[domInfo])
}

// access your own object
var mynode = new InputExt();
mynode.info("attributes")

// access document prototype
HTMLInputElement.prototype.logme = function(){
   console.log('me')
}

var element = document.body.appendChild(mynode.inputnode);
element.logme()
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that. I wanted it to be uniform - the instance of my class being a full-blown `HTMLElement`. Do I just have to make a custom constructor function which returns created `HTMLElement` injected with methods and fields, ditching `prototype` and `new`?