# First try at JavaScript Prototyping

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am just getting my feet wet where JavaScript Prototyping is involved, and I am having some trouble.

I need to create a `_LEAVE` object from a `LEAVE` prototype for a system I am working on based on a prototype object. The `_LEAVE` object has a function named `Ready`, which should fire when the document is ready. The system already has similar functionality in some of it's older code, and I am trying to keep it uniform.

Here is the code I am trying, but I keep getting an error:

```
var LEAVE = function () {

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    _LEAVE.Ready();
});


var _LEAVE = function (params) {

    this.Ready = function () {
        alert ("Leave Ready");
    };
}

_LEAVE.prototype = new LEAVE();
```

Error:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'Ready' 
>       leave.js, line 6 character 5

I'm not sure where I am going wrong, as this seems to be what is happening in other parts of the system. At least, something similar is happening, but I am struggling to wrap my mind around the old code...

Would appreciate any advice anyone could give me! :-)

Comment: It looks like you don't quite have a grasp of how prototypes really work in JS.  You're kinda close though.  I'm sure someone will get you the correct answer here shortly but in the meantime check out this quick tut on Prototyping: http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#prototypepatternjavascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've understood you correctly, but are you attempting to create an *instance* of a `LEAVE` object? If so, `LEAVE` needs to be a constructor function, and `Ready` should be a method on the `prototype` of that:

```
var LEAVE = function () {};
LEAVE.prototype.Ready = function () {
    alert("Leave Ready");
};
```

Now, you can instantiate `LEAVE` by calling the constructor with the `new` operator:

```
var _LEAVE = new LEAVE(); // _LEAVE is an instance of LEAVE
$(document).ready(function () {
    _LEAVE.Ready(); // Ready is a method of `LEAVE.prototype`
});
```

Methods declared as properties of the `prototype` object are shared by all instances. So all instances of `LEAVE` will have a `.Ready` method available to them, but they will share one copy of the function in memory (the copy that was assigned to the property of `LEAVE.prototype`).

Answer (score 0):

What you have done here is just inherited the child _LEAVE function from parent LEAVE function. But if you want to call a method in the child class, you need to create an instance of it. So you need to create an instance of the _LEAVE class. just add this line :

var **_LEAVE_OBJECT = new _LEAVE();**

and use **_LEAVE_OBJECT.Ready()** instead of _LEAVE.Ready(); in $(document).ready.

Modified code :

```
var LEAVE = function () {

}

$(document).ready(function () {
 _LEAVE_OBJECT.Ready();
});


var _LEAVE = function (params) {
   this.Ready = function () {
    alert ("Leave Ready");
    };  
}
_LEAVE.prototype = new LEAVE();
var _LEAVE_OBJECT = new _LEAVE();
```

Comment: If u find above code is useful for u, please mark it as useful. Because I'm not even reputed to mark a question as useful :)