# Prototype difference between function declaration and expression

Tags: javascript

```
var foo = function(){alert('foo')}
function bar(){alert('bar')}
```

Why does `foo.prototype` point to Object, but the named function `bar.prototype` points to itself?

I should add that this behavior is observed from browser console.

Comment: Sorry. What are you trying to say? Both `foo.prototype` and `bar.prototype` should point to the `prototype` object of `foo` and `bar` respectively.

Comment: Your question makes no sense - `foo.prototype` does not point to `Object` and `bar.prototype` does not point to `bar`: http://jsfiddle.net/2xkpC/

Comment: @AaditMShah You're right, but the Chrome console logs the function name when you ask for the function's prototype. I'll keep my answer deleted until I figure it out.

Comment: @bfavaretto - The Chrome console logs the function name because the `prototype` object of a function has a property called `constructor` which points back to the function. All functions have a property called `name` which holds the name of the function. For unnamed functions the Chrome console simply prints out `Object` instead of an empty string.

Comment: See the following answer for more information about JavaScript inheritance and the `prototype` property: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a console such a Chrome to log the value of a `prototype` object then I suggest you don't. The Chrome console, like other browser consoles, formats the output of the prototype object.

So for a named function it will log the `name` of the function, but for an unnamed function it will simply log `Object`. This does not mean that the `prototype` of the function points to `Object` or the function itself. It's just that that's what the console is showing you (someone should sue them for that). See for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/2xkpC/

How does it know the name of a function from it's `prototype`? Well, the prototype of a function has a property called `constructor` which points back to the function itself, and the name of the function is stored as a string in a property called `name` on the function. So if you log a `prototype` object then it will display `prototype.constructor.name || "Object"`:

```
var foo = function(){alert('foo')}
console.log(foo.prototype); // logs "Object"

function bar(){alert('bar')}
console.log(bar.prototype); // logs bar.prototype.constructor.name
```

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/4bWfn/

If you open your console and click that triangle near the logged output then you'll see the `constructor` and the `__proto__` properties of the prototype object. Under `constructor` you'll also see the `name` property.

To know more about inheritance in JavaScript and the `prototype` object read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743

Comment: Agree, the console's behavior is very misleading. Possible reason for this behavior is to log the constructor's name for new instances, i.e., `var b = new bar(); console.log(b); // bar`.

Answer (score -1):

Because `var foo` in your example it is pointer to anonymous function.

compare to

```
var foo = function me(){alert('foo');}
test=foo;
console.log(test.prototype);
```

here `var foo` is pointer to named function.

Comment: `function(){//do something}` itself anonymous function regradless of context, there is no reason to devide that to two different types

Comment: yes, my example is to compare to OP example, my example shows named function, it is almost equal to answer of @bfavaretto