# confusion with javascript prototype object

Tags: javascript, prototype

when we create an object like this

```
function Person(first,last){

this.first = first;
this.last = last;
this.full = function (){
   alert(this.first + " " + this.last); 
   }
}

obj = new Person('abdul','raziq');
```

could we also add to obj's prototype anything like this

```
obj.prototype = 'some functions or anything ';
```

or its not possible once we created the object ?

and there is a `__proto__` property on person object

obj.`__proto__`

but when i access obj.prototype property its undefined ?

can someone pls explain in a simple way possible

Comment: The answer is yes, you can add to the prototype after an object instance is created.

Comment: i have modified my question pls read it once again

Comment: i want to add to obj prototype property , is it possible to add to obj prototype property something

Comment: objects does not have prototype property

Comment: Only functions have a `prototype` property. Add it to the prototype of the constructor function instead.

Comment: thank u very much , but does obj have __proto__ property ?

Answer (score 1):

The `prototype` property only exists on functions, not on instances of functions. Read this StackOverflow answer to know more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
Person.prototype.full = function(){
   alert(this.first + " " + this.last); 
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zS7yE/)

The prototype object is attached to the `Class` not to the instance so yes you can add/remove properties to/from prototype after instances are created. And all instances of the type will reflect the changes made.

Comment: sorry i have corrected my question pls read it once again thanks