# Overriding methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype, overriding

I would like to know what is the difference between overriding methods with prototypes and without prototypes. Consider:

**Example 1:**

```
function Animal() {
    this.sleep = function () {
        alert("animal sleeping");
    };

    this.eat = function () {
        alert("animal eating");
    };
}

function Dog() {
    this.eat = function () {
        alert("Dog eating");
    };
}

Dog.prototype = new Animal;

var dog = new Dog;

dog.eat();
```

**Example 2:**

```
function Animal() { }

function Dog() { }

Animal.prototype.sleep = function () {
    alert("animal sleeping");
};

Animal.prototype.eat = function () {
    alert("animal eating");
};

Dog.prototype = new Animal;

Dog.prototype.eat = function () {
    alert("Dog eating");
};

var dog = new Dog;

dog.eat();
```

I feel both examples produce the same effect that the `Dog` class is overriding the eat method of the `Animal` class. Or is there anything different happening?

Comment: You should use `this` keyword when defining the  properties of an object in its constructor.

Comment: @Sann sorry missed the this keyword. Edited the question now.

Comment: It's almost always a good idea to put methods on the prototype as then they are shared among all instances. Putting them in your constructor copies them across all instances and this consumes more memory.

Comment: So apart from memory concerns, is there any other issue?

Comment: @DeepakMahalingam - Functions declared as properties of `this` inside a constructor prevent the private variables of the constructor from being garbage collected even though they may not close over any private variables themselves. However since this can be classified as a _memory concern_ I would say: no, there are no other issues. It's just popular coding practice to put methods on the `prototype`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the first method each of the `Animal` instance will get its own implementation of `sleep` and `eat` methods.

While in the second model All instances will share the same instance of the `sleep` and `eat` methods.

The second model is better since we can share the methods.

Answer (score 10):

As Arun mentioned in the first example you're creating `sleep` and `eat` functions for each new instance. In the second example there's only one `sleep` and `eat` function which is shared amongst all the instances.

In this case the second method is better, but it's good to know when to use the first method and when to use the second. A little bit of theory first:

**Note:** There are four kinds of variables in JavaScript - `private`, `public`, `shared` and `static`.

Private variables are inaccessible outside of the function in which they are defined. For example:

```
function f() {
    var x; // this is a private variable
}
```

Public variables are defined on the `this` object inside a function. For example:

```
function f() {
    this.x; // this is a public variable
}
```

Shared variables are shared on the `prototype` of the function. For example:

```
function f() {}

f.prototype.x; // this is a shared variable
```

Static variables are properties of the function itself. For example:

```
function f() {}

f.x; // this is a static variable
```

Most often it's best to declare the methods of a constructor function as shared methods since all instances of the constructor share them. However if your method needs to access a private variable then it must be declared as a public method itself.

**Note:** This is my own nomenclature. Not many JavaScript programmers adhere to it. Others seem to follow Douglas Crockford's nomenclature: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

To know more about prototypal inheritance in JavaScript read the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743

Answer (score 0):

In your first example each new `Dog` instance will have it's own `eat` method and in the second example there will be only one `eat` method on `Dog.prototype`, which will be shared between all future instances of `Dog` like Arun mentioned.

This is the only *"tricky"* difference between those two. But it's always better to define methods on the `prototype` to avoid high memory consumption and leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The methods in first example are defined in object instance.

You're setting the `Dog` prototype to a new `Animal` instance, thus `Dog` will inherit `sleep` and `eat` functions from `Animal`. Then you're **DEFINING** (NOT **OVERRIDING**) `eat` method in `Dog` constructor as an instance method, and this will **HIDE** the inherited `eat` method in `Dog` instances.

Consider the following example:

```
function LittleDog() { }
LittleDog.prototype = Object.create(Dog.prototype);
(new LittleDog()).eat();
```

The code above will alert `animal eating` with your code in first example.

And will alert `Dog eating` with the code in the second one.