# the prototype - add function to a class

Tags: javascript

Im curently learning about the prototype. Is it better to put the  function "sayName" in the class or add it later via a prototype?  or is it the same and depends on the situation?

```
function Animal(name,numLegs){
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;
    this.sayName = function(){
         console.log("Hi my name is " + this.name);

    };
}


var penguin = new Animal("Captain Cook", 2);
penguin.sayName();
```

or

```
function Animal(name,numLegs){
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;
}

Animal.prototype.sayName = function(){
    console.log("Hi my name is " + this.name);
};


var penguin = new Animal("Captain Cook", 2);
penguin.sayName();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding methods in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497259/overriding-methods-in-javascript)

Comment: See my **comments** on these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71923547/1599699 https://stackoverflow.com/a/62142995/1599699

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the same, as the first version will use more memory, as ever instance of `Animal` has its own `this.sayName`. In the latter, all `Animal` instances have access on *the same* `sayName`:

```
function Animal(name,numLegs){
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;
    this.sayName = function(){
         console.log("Hi my name is " + this.name);
    };
}

var dog = new Animal(4, "Jack");
var alligator = new Animal(4, "Snap");

dog.sayName = function(){ console.log("woof"); }

dog.sayName();
alligator.sayName();
```

Will result in

```
woof
Hi my name is Snap
```

because `dog` and `alligator` don't share same the function `sayName`, whereas a change to the prototype in your latter example would change all calls of `sayName`.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use prototype for shared resources

Comment: A pitfall would be if you use plain objects in the prototype – they can surprisingly be mutated from one instance to another.

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answered - it depends upon the situation. Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15497685/783743

If your method needs to access private variables of the constructor then you have no option other than to define it inside the constructor. Otherwise you should always declare them on the `prototype` object.

You should also read the following articles:

1. http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743