# How to add an method to a class in Javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, class, methods, prototype, ecmascript-5

I need do add a method to a Javascript class using the new syntax. I tried this way:

```
class X{

    constructor() {
        this.a = 'b'
    }

    x(){

    }
}

X.prototype.y = function (){
    console.log('y')
}

var x = new X()

x.y()

console.log(X) // print the  the class but not the new method.
```

It just prints:

```
class X{

    constructor() {
        this.a = 'b'
    }

    x(){}
}
```

But I expected

```
class X{

        constructor() {
            this.a = 'b'
        }

        x(){}

        y(){
            console.log('y');
        }
    }
```

How could I add a new method to a Javascript class?

Comment: just for sake of knowledge: I heard that javascript is classless. What does it means?

Comment: I expected the new method showed in the log, inside the class. Console.log(X) should log the class code.

Comment: You added method to the prototype, not as own property. Read about difference.

Comment: How could I add the method as a property using EcmaScript 6 sugar syntax? Note that I need to add a method after class declaration given the fact I will receive method name and parameter names as strings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this works fine, if you are checking this in google chrome console, then please check by expanding **proto** node.
or alternatively try checking 
`console.log(X.y)`
or `console.log(X.prototype.y)`
or `console.log(x.y)`
this must print that function

Comment: I need y acting like x. For example, when I log X it must print Both x and y inside X.

Answer (score 6):

There are two major ways to add methods to a class, this can be within the scope of the class when writing the code or using ".prototype" to attach a method to your class.
Below is an example of adding a method within the class scope:

```js
class Person {
   constructor(fName, lName) {
      this.firstName = fName;
      this.lastName = lName;
   }
   sayName = function() {
   return `My Name is ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
   }
}
const firstPerson= new Person ("Thor", "Odinson")
console.log(firstPerson.sayName())
```

And below an example of a method creation from outside the scope of a class using a prototype:

```js
class Person {
   constructor(fName, lName) {
      this.firstName = fName;
      this.lastName = lName;
   }
}
Person.prototype.sayName = function() {
   return `My Name is ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
}
const secondPerson= new Person ("Tony", "Stark")
console.log(secondPerson.sayName())
```

A very important thing to note is that using prototype to add a method to a class doesn't change the structure of the class. So logging the object won't render the method. But the method is available to all subclasses and instances of that class.

Comment: So basically, by adding things to a class's or non-bound function's `.prototype` like above, you're adding those things to every single instance of the class or function, **including** those which have already been created, **except for** the properties of the instances which have been assigned since their instantiation (`new`). That is to say that, essentially, the prototype properties of a class or function are the "fallback" properties, if they haven't been set on the instance.

Comment: And if they have been set on the instance, even if you later assign or re-assign the property to the prototype, it will not be rewritten on the already-instantiated instances... It's important also to understand that there might be some caveats to manually modifying `.prototype` in the cases where you're doing atypical things with your types, like iterating through or copying from prototypes...

Comment: For more information, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain https://developer.chrome.com/blog/smooshgate/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Object.setPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf).

Example:

```
// A class…
class Someone {
  constructor(qui){
    this.qui = qui
  } 
}

// A mixins with new methods
class MyMixins {
  says(quoi){
    console.log(this.qui + " says "+ quoi)
  }
  eats(quoi){
    console.log(this.qui + " eats "+quoi)
  }
}

// An instance…
const marion = new Someone("Marion")

// This fails…
//marion.says("hello!")
//marion.eats("potatoes")

//-----> Here's the trick <------
Object.setPrototypeOf(Someone.prototype, MyMixins.prototype);

// This pass…
marion.says("hello!")   //=> "Marion says hello!"
marion.eats("potatoes") //=> "Marion eats potatoes"
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit late, but would this have solved your problem back then?

```js
class XWithY extends X {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
  y() {
    console.log('y')
  }
}

const xwy = new XWithY();

console.log(xwy instanceof X); // outputs true
```

Comment: No this is not adding a method to an existing class, this is creating an instance and adding a method to that. However, this may be the better method of doing things.