# Inheriting from a parent object will execute its parent constructor?

Tags: javascript

All , In the classical inheritance language. such as Java , c# etc, It is true a new instance initialization of a sub Class will cause the base Class constructor execution before the sub Class's constructor is executed. But I am not sure whether It will be same in the javascript inheritance.
Let's take a example . Says your have the code like below .

```
function Shape() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
};
```

If there is an object name `rect` inherit from `Shape` . supposed the constructor of `Rectangle` looks like this.

```
function Rectangle(){

};
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
var rect= new Rectangle();
```

Would the constructor `Shape` will be executed when the constructor `Rectangle` is executed ? thanks.

Comment: In Javascript there is no concept as constructors, everything is functions. reference : **www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html**

Comment: Really ?What I had knew is when the `new` expression is executed, the `function` becomes the object's constructor.  without the `new` , the function is just a block of code .

Comment: How difficult is it to add an `alert` in the parent's constructor ?

Comment: @alfasin  I see. I already knew the answer. I just don't know why . thanks.

Comment: Should I close it ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you normally do inheritance in JavaScript:

```
function Shape() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}

function Rectangle() {
    Shape.call(this);
}

Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
```

Notice that you're calling `Shape.call(this)` from inside the `Rectangle` constructor. This is like calling the base/super class constructor in other languages. Without doing so your `Rectangle` objects would not have the `x` and `y` properties defined inside the `Shape` constructor.

For more details read the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15497685/783743

Comment: Thanks your kindly answer , It is nice to meet you again. :) actually I found what I really want to ask is another question. Could you please review [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129365/in-prototype-inheritance-program-when-a-property-not-found-in-a-specified-object)