# In prototype inheritance program when a property not found in a specified object

Tags: javascript

All, After reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816071/prototype-based-vs-class-based-inheritance), and did some test based on it .

```
        function Shape() {
            this.x = 0;
            this.y = 0;
        };

        Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
            this.x += x;
            this.y += y;
            console.log("Shape moved.");
        };

        // Rectangle - subclass
        function Rectangle() {
            //Shape.call(this); //call super constructor.
        };

        Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);

        var rect = new Rectangle();
                    alert(rect.x);
```

If I commented the code `Shape.call(this);` in the `Rectangle`, I found the `rect.x` is `underfined` instead of the value `0`.

And What make me confused is that I found in the best answer of the [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816071/prototype-based-vs-class-based-inheritance) said:

*"In javascript, every object has a secret link to the object which created it,forming a chain. When an object is asked for a property that it does not have,its parent object is asked... continually up the chain until the property is found or until the root object is reached."*

So I can't understand why the `rect` can't found `x` in the prototype chain. The `rect` is already inherited form `Shape`. If the `x` doesn't exist in the `rect`, It supposed be found in his parent. right ?
And in my understanding .If using `Shape.call(this);` , It just add a new `x` property to the `rect`, well ,that would not be a code reusing the original `x` from parents. It just like the override property in the classical inheritance . that is add a new property into the sub class which have the same name and type as the one in the base class..I don't know if my understanding is right , if not . please correct me .Or was I missing something I didn't noticed ? thanks.

**Edit**

Below is my understanding based on the Thilo and Arun P Johny 's answers. please correct me if it is not right.

Before inheritance happen.

[image]

After inheritance executed.

[image]

So the `x` only belong to the instance constructed by `Shape`. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't call the super constructor, then `this.x = 0` is not executed so `x` remains undefined.

If you wanted it to appear in the prototype, you'd have to say `Shape.prototype.x = 0`, I think.

> So I can't understand why the `rect` can't find `x` in the prototype chain.

It's because the prototype does not have `x` either. It only has `move`. The `x` gets assigned to individual instances in the constructor (but only if you call it).

Comment: Friend , I am also in china. If do so , I think That is a new `x` distinct from the `x` in the super object ... Is it against OOP inheritance ?

Comment: If you want inheritance to work "all the way" you probably have to call the super constructors.

Comment: In prototypical inheritance, constructors are not inherited, only prototypical values are inherited

Comment: If you want to copy the constructor then you may have to call `Shape.call(this)` inside `Rectangle` constructor as you have done(but commented)

Comment: Hi , Guys ,Could you please verify my updated? I updated it based your kindly answers and comments.

Answer (score 1):

Arun P Johny is right (you should read his comment!)

Try this:

```
    function Shape() {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    };

    Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
        console.log("Shape moved.");
    };


    // Rectangle - subclass
    function Rectangle() {            
    };

    Rectangle.prototype = new Shape();
    var rect = new Rectangle();
    alert(rect.x);
```

You can call `Shape.call(this);` like you did (commented) in your code, but this way it's not a "real" inheritance since you won't be able to use `move()` in Rectangle.

But the code above is a mishmash of "new" and prototypes and hence very confusing. I guess that what you really want to do is something like this:

```
   var Shape = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        move: function(x, y) {
            this.x += x;
            this.y += y;
            alert("Shape moved: ["+this.x+","+this.y+"]");
        }
    };

    var rect = Object.create(Shape);
    alert(rect.x);
    rect.move(2,3);
    rect.move(1,1);
```

Comment: Yes, I think the most valuable comments is `In prototypical inheritance, constructors are not inherited, only prototypical values are inherited`.

Comment: I think that the word "prototype" might be a litle bit confusing: Prototypal inheritance is when one object inherits the properties of another object - no classes are involved (hence no constructor) - there is no "template" that creates objects!

Comment: I see. except when `call(this)`.

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment

Comment: :)  forget about it . What I understand from your comment `no template` means the object initialized state is `{}` no matter what object it is inherited from, right ?

Comment: no that's not what I said. A "template" is another way to describe a "class". If your "class" is `function Rectangle() {}` then yes - the object's initial state is empty.

Comment: calling `Rectangle.prototype = Shape.prototype;` or `Rectangle.prototype = new Shape();` allows Rectangle to adopt all the properties of Shape.

Comment: It looks very flexible...:)

Comment: I think that it'll be easier to grasp if you'll have a look on the second code example I just posted.

Comment: hm...Actually, I am trying to find a best practice of implement inheritance :)

Comment: Since JS is a prototypical language, I believe that the best practice is using Prototypal inheritance.

Comment: Yes, you know , The difficulty of it is how to make the code elegant and accessible.

Comment: Well, I find the second code example I added here very elegant - it's Douglas Crockford style ;)

Comment: friend, @alfasin, one of shortcomings I can find in your second code example is can not `new` a `rect`, that means there is no constructor for object initialization. It will make the initialization code looks not elegant. So I think the code I post is better one. all the initialization code is in the constructor. :)

Comment: The original link is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

Comment: If you're going to use JS intensively, I highly recommend on reading this: http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html and: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2709811/1057429

Comment: :) I don't know why ,I just prefer to the code looks more like in a traditional style. but in essence, Javascript is a prototype based programming language which is different from the classical based programming language.