# JavaScript: looping through string with 'for' behaving unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, string

This is a two part question.

I wrote a function to find the index of a substring inside a bigger string with the following function

```
function indexOf(str){
  for (var x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
    if(this[x] === str) {
      return x;
    }
  }
    return -1;
  };
```

I then set:

```
var string1="bbbabbaaa"
var string2="ab"
```

Then I called my function in this manner:

```
string1.indexOf(string2)
```

I was expecting to see -1 in the result because I was expecting the for loop to go through the characters in the string one by one and compare each letter to the string "ab". Since no single letter is equivalent to "ab", it shouldn't find a match. But what actually returned was 3, which is the index of "a". So my first question is, what happened here? how did the `if(this[3] === str)` return true, isn't it basically comparing "a" with "ab", which should return false right?

if I modify my function to pass string1 in as an argument, I get the expected `-1`:

```
function AlternativeIndexOf(str,str2){
  for (var x = 0; x < str.length; x++) {
    if(str[x] === str2) {
      return x;
    }
  }
    return -1;
  };
```

calling the function this way `AlternativeIndexOf(string1, string2)`, returns -1.

So my second question is, hows is calling the function `AlternativeIndexOf(string1, string2)` differ from calling the function  `string1.indexOf(string2)`

Comment: What do you think "this" is? Why do you think your routine will be called when you call string.indexOf?  Have you viewed the console? Have you walked through the code with the debugger?

Comment: It's not using your `indexOf()`, function, but https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score 2):

```
string1.indexOf(string2)
```

This is using Javascript native **[String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)** method and not the one created by you, you are trying to [override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497259/overriding-methods-in-javascript) the `.indexOf` function but the way you are doing it is not correct, instead try to redefine the `String.prototype.indexOf`

```
String.prototype.indexOf = function(elem) {
    // Put your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start, as another answer has mentioned, you need to assign to `String.prototype.indexOf`.

> So my first question is, what happened here? how did the if(this[3] === str) return true, isn't it basically comparing "a" with "ab", which should return false right?

Your function isn't being called. The function being called is `String.prototype.indexOf` (which you haven't overwritten), and it's behaving correctly; your understanding of `String.prototype.indexOf` is broken. See [the `String.prototype.indexOf` manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) for more information. Here's an example, from that manual, of what `String.prototype.indexOf` should return when the second argument is a string:

> 'Blue Whale'.indexOf('Blue');     // returns  0

You have two strings; you should be using one loop nested inside of another to loop on characters of both strings, comparing them. For example:

```
String.prototype.indexOf = function(str) {
    for (var x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
        var y = 0;
        while (y < str.length && this[x+y] == str[y]) {
            y++;
        }
        if (y == str.length) {
            return x;
        }
    }
    return -1;
};
```