# Issue with overwriting prototype with object in javascript

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

Trying to understand prototypes. I'm playing around in Chrome's console and was hoping someone  can point me to why this is happening.

```
function Gadget(name, color) {
     this.name = name;
     this.color = color;
     this.whatAreYou = function(){
       return 'I am a ' + this.color + ' ' + this.name;
     }
}

Gadget.prototype.price = 100;
Gadget.prototype.rating = 3;
Gadget.prototype.getInfo = function() {
    return 'Rating: ' + this.rating + ', price: ' + this.price;
};

var newtoy = new Gadget('webcam', 'black');

newtoy.constructor.prototype

Gadget {price: 100, rating: 3, getInfo: function} //Expected
```

**Now if I try the following, prototype does not have the expected results.**

```
function Gadget(name, color) {
     this.name = name;
     this.color = color;
     this.whatAreYou = function(){
       return 'I am a ' + this.color + ' ' + this.name;
     }
}

Gadget.prototype = {
     price: 100,
     rating: 3,
     getInfo: function() {
       return 'Rating: ' + this.rating + ', price: ' + this.price;
     }
};

var newtoy = new Gadget('webcam', 'black');

newtoy.constructor.prototype

Object {} //Empty Object!!!!!???
```

Comment: Are you looking for `newtoy.__proto__`? ie what are you seeking going through `newtoy.constructor`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8RRn6/)**

This is because you overwrote the prototype instead of extending it when you did this:

```
Gadget.prototype =
```

It is common when overwriting it, to make a facade of the constructor like this:

```
Gadget.prototype = {
 constructor : Gadget
}
```

So for your exact situation:

```
Gadget.prototype = {
 constructor : Gadget,
 price: 100,
 rating: 3,
 getInfo: function() {
   return 'Rating: ' + this.rating + ', price: ' + this.price;
 }
};
```

Comment: That is the problem, but it would be more helpful if you explained how to do it properly. I will upvote it if you do

Comment: Ah...that actually makes sense.  I'm reading the book Object-Oriented Javascript by Stoyan Stefanov and he does this but fails to mention clearly the repercussions, or I failed to realize.

Answer (score 1):

Prototype is initially a special typed object. When you assign the prototype with a new object (the curly braces are short hand for a new object) you lose the special prototype object.

See [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work) for a deeper explanation.