# Setting prototypes inside function constructor

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
var a = function(){
    this.sayFoo = function(){
        console.log('foo');
    };
}

var b = function(){
    console.log(this.prototype); //undefined
    this.sayBar = function(){
        console.log('bar');
    };
}

b.prototype = new a();

var bInst = new b();

bInst.sayFoo();
bInst.sayBar();

console.log(b.prototype); //a {sayFoo: function}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KbBny/1/

How do I add `sayBar` to the `b` prototype inside the function constructor?

Does `b.prototype = new a();` overwrite the prototype, or merge `b`'s with `a`'s?

Comment: The whole idea of a prototype is that you define it *outside* of the constructor, rather than inside.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743

Comment: I can totally understand the wish to set the property inside the constructor, because setting it outside looks so disconnected. Added my own wrapperbased solution further down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does `b.prototype = new a();` overwrite the prototype, or merge b's with a's?

It does overwrite it with a new `a` instance; nothing is merged (for example you'd need to update the `b.prototype.constructor` property). That's why you do add all properties to `b.prototype` *after* this line. However, actually you don't want to create an instance, but just set up the prototype chain correctly:

```
b.prototype = Object.create(a.prototype);
```

> How do I add sayBar to the b prototype inside the function constructor?

You should not add it to the prototype, as it is not a prototype (shared) method - it's instance-specific to every `a` instance (at least it should be, otherwise you would put it on `a.prototype` and then it gets covered by above line). To get the instance method on all `b` instances as well, you use

```
var b = function(){
    a.call(this); // invoke the `a` constructor on this instance
};
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure if I'm following you on the last part. If I use `this.sayBar = ...` inside the b construcor function, it would have to be redefined for each instance of b, right? Wouldn't it be better to add it to the prototype?

Comment: @alex23 no, functions are _not_ always in the prototype.

Comment: @alex23 Then please explain why I don' see two methods in the console: http://jsfiddle.net/KbBny/2/

Comment: @alex23 no, a function added with `this.func = function() { ... }` is a direct property of that object, and doesn't touch the prototype at all.

Comment: @alex23: No, not those on `this`. You really should read [prototype vs this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/310870/1048572)

Comment: @Alnitak Would it be possible to add something to the prototype inside of the constructor function?

Comment: @Johan it's possible, but you shouldn't do it, because the constructor is called once _per instance_, but the prototype is shared amongst _all_ instances.

Comment: @Johan: correctly. Your `sayFoo` and `sayBar` functions are currently redefined for each instance. Since they don't need access to any closure variables, they better should be on the prototype. And don't listen to alex23.

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, I know. That's why I want to add stuff to the prototype instead of `this`. But I suppose that I can't add it inside the constructor then.

Comment: That's right.  And the corollary of that is that functions on the prototype cannot access lexically scoped variables bound inside the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the correct inheritance pattern.

Use:

```
b.prototype = Object.create(a.prototype);
```

In your case you are performing a simple override, you are not correctly establishing inheritance. `Object.create` is ES5, but you could polyfill with this:

**Object.create**

```
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            throw new Error('Object.create implementation only accepts the first parameter.');
        }
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
```

**Accessing the prototype**

You can't access the `prototype` inside the definition block. You have a `this` reference for that.

```
var b = function() {
    a.call(this);
    b.prototype.doSomething = function() {console.log("b");}; 
};
b.prototype = Object.create(a.prototype);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/a9Gwr/1/)**

Comment: Does this merge the prototypes? And how is the browser support for `Object.create`?

Comment: Thanks, would it be enough to include the source for `Object.create` in order to support it in older browsers? Or does it rely on other functions?

Comment: @Johan https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill

Comment: Ok, and the final question which I don't believe you have answered yet. How do I access the b prototype inside the function?

Comment: @alex23 Inside the `b` constructor function.

Answer (score 0):

## **prototype *Sort of* inside constructor**

You could use a wrapping function. I believe they are called decoratorfunctions in Javascript. Where you set the prototype. And then when you use that decoratorfunction as a constructor, you wont have to set the prototype separately. It will so to speak be set inside a function that acts as a constructor.

```
function Human(name, lastname, age) {
  function _human(name, lastname, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.age = age;
  }
  _human.prototype.sayName = function() {
    console.log(this.name + " " + this.lastname);
  }
  var temp = new _human(name, lastname, age);
  return temp;
}
```

Then you just do:

```
var person = new Human("John", "Doe", 25);
console.log(person);
person.sayName();
```