# basic javascript inherits issue

Tags: javascript, inheritance

for a better structure I try to inherits on my classes in Javascript. Maybe my Approach is completely wrong or infeasible. Here is my Example Code:

```
function myMotherClass(value){
   this.MyValue = value
}

function myChildClass(value){
    this.prototype = new myMotherClass(value);
    this.alert = function(){
        alert(value);
    };
}

//myChildClass.prototype = new myMotherClass(1)

var myClass = new myChildClass(2);
myClass.alert();
```

[here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ipad0214/4b9ZH/)!

As you can see in my fiddle, if you use the commented line it is working fine.

if you can see the fiddle, i am trying to give the cunstructor value in myChildClass to the base "myMotherClass". But as you can see, there is a undefined output.

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Comment: Generally the kind of example posted by OP is achieved by using ``constructor`` and ``prototype chain`` Please refer [Classical Inheritance in JavaScript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html).

Comment: See [Setting prototypes inside function constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582608/setting-prototypes-inside-function-constructor) for an almost duplicate discussion.

Comment: @sarbbottam: Except that in that article, Crockford makes the classic mistake of calling the parent constructor when creating the child contructor's prototype, which is an anti-pattern and doesn't even work correctly with his example (`Parenizor` expects to receive a `value` argument, but `ZParenizor.inherits(Parenizor);` calls `Parenizor` without one [inside `inherits`]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it sort of seems to work with the commented out line is that `myChildClass` in that commented-out line is the *function*; but in the line inside the `myChildClass` constructor, `this` is not the *function*, it's the instance created by the `new` operator. The `prototype` property on functions is the object that will be assigned by the `new` operator to the new instances it creates, as their underlying prototype; there is no special meaning to the `prototype` property on *instances* (it doesn't, for instance, refer to the instance's underlying prototype).

The correct way to do this is this:

```
// Parent constructor
function myMotherClass(value){
   this.MyValue = value
}

// Child constructor
function myChildClass(value){
    // Chain to parent constructor, passing any necessary args
    myMotherClass.call(this, value);

    // Other child stuff -- see note below
    this.alert = function(){
        alert(value);
    };
}

// Set up inheritance by creating myChildClass's prototype
// property to be an object that is baked by myMotherClass's
// prototype object; do NOT *call* myMotherClass here, it's
// a common anti-pattern you'll see in a lot of examples
inherit(myMotherClass, myChildClass);

// Create an instance    
var myClass = new myChildClass(2);
myClass.alert();
```

...where `inherit` is:

```
function inherit(parent, child) {
    var temp;

    if (Object.create) {
        child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
    } else {
        temp = function() { };
        temp.prototype = parent.prototype;
        child.prototype = new temp();
    }
    child.prototype.constructor = child;
}
```

Note that with the way you're defining `alert`, this slightly strange behavior occurs:

```
var o = new myChildClass(42);
console.log(o.MyValue); // 42
o.alert();              // alerts "42"
o.MyValue = 67;
console.log(o.MyValue); // 67
o.alert();              // alerts "42" <== !!!
```

You can change how you define `alert` so it uses `MyValue` like this:

```
this.alert = function() {
    alert(this.MyValue);
};
```

...provided you always call it through the instance. (More on my blog: *Mythical methods*)

But if you're going to do that, you can move it to the prototype -- put this after the `inherit` call that sets up the chain:

```
myChildClass.prototype.alert = function(){
    alert(this.MyValue);
};
```

Here's that all put together:

```
// Parent constructor
function myMotherClass(value){
   this.MyValue = value
}

// Child constructor
function myChildClass(value){
    // Chain to parent constructor, passing any necessary args
    myMotherClass.call(this, value);

    // Other child stuff...
}

// Set up inheritance by creating myChildClass's prototype
// property to be an object that is baked by myMotherClass's
// prototype object; do NOT *call* myMotherClass here
inherit(myMotherClass, myChildClass);

// Add stuff to myChildClass's prototype property
myChildClass.prototype.alert = function(){
    alert(this.MyValue);
};

// Create an instance    
var myClass = new myChildClass(2);
myClass.alert();
```

If you're interested in classical inheritance in JavaScript, I have a handy helper script, `Lineage`, that makes the above simpler and adds a few useful features: http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/

Comment: Hej, thank you for this big and detailed answer, i will try your suggestions and mark it as answer as soon as i tried it :-)

Comment: @Ipad: You're welcome. BTW, through an editing error I left a variable declared in `inherit` that it never uses, cleaned up above. :-)