# Javascript Prototypes,objects,constructor??i am confused

Tags: javascript, class, oop, methods, constructor

I have gone through plenty of Stack Overflow question that had description but I seriously found them very confusing. What I want is a simple explanation,please don't refer a link.

I'm totally confused, completely jumbled up between:

- Prototypes,
- Objects,
- Constructor

I have done plenty of research but I found them very complicated.

Any simple explanation??

Comment: Did you ever googled them ? Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FA_re-introduction_to_JavaScript).

Comment: yes!!i went through a lot of them,i got familiarised with the suyntax,but i din`t got the concept thoroughly,evrything is still very vague in my mind

Comment: You need to be more specific what exactly is it that you don't understand. Otherwise it's very hard to do anything other than repeat what is said everywhere else.

Comment: This is too big of a question for the StackOverflow format. You will need to break your questions into something smaller. OOP in javascript  takes about a book to explain, and just Prototype use takes at least an entire chapter. Is there something specific about the prototypes that doesn't make sense?

Comment: I guess time to read a good JS book. Refer JS Page at stackoverflow [http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info] for references

Comment: Yes,just wait 2 min.i ll simplify the question

Comment: what is the difference between prototype and constructor?

Comment: http://blog.pluralsight.com/2013/03/19/understanding-javascript-prototypes/                                                         Read this blog which might help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're in luck. There's a very simple explanation:

**Step One: Create an Object**

Say you want to circle:

```
var circle = {};
```

**Step Two: Give it Some Properties**

A circle can be drawn, so let's create a property called `draw`:

```
circle.draw = function () {
    // drawing logic
};
```

1. A property is simply a variable belonging to an object. A variable by itself is not a property.
2. Properties and variables can hold any kind of data. Functions in JavaScript is data.
3. When a property holds a function it's called a method.

Hence we have a method called `draw` belonging to the object `circle`.

**Step Three: Extend an Object**

Now I want a ball and a ball is kind of like a circle. So let's extend `circle` to create a ball:

```
var ball = Object.create(circle);
```

1. Here we took the object `circle` and used it to create a new object called `ball`.
2. The object `ball` now has all the properties of `circle`. So we can call `ball.draw`.
3. The object `circle` is the prototype of `ball`.

**Step Four: Give it Some Properties**

Every ball has a `radius`, so let's give ours one:

```
ball.radius = 5;
```

**Step Five: Create a Constructor**

There's a problem here. Every time I want to create a new ball I extend `circle` and manually define the `radius` of the ball. Instead I would like a function to create the ball and give it a radius for me. This function is called a constructor:

```
function createBall(radius) {
    var ball = Object.create(circle);
    ball.radius = radius;
    return ball;
}

var baseball = createBall(5);
var basketball = createBall(10);

baseball.draw();
basketball.draw();
```

That's pretty much all you need to know about prototypes, objects and constructors.

Of course there's a lot more explanation but it's too much for one StackOverflow answer. I wrote a blog post on it, and I'm not planning to rewrite the same thing here. You should read my blog. It's worth it: http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters

---

**Edit:** Sure, I'll explain what happening in that code: http://cssdeck.com/labs/4ksohwya

First, scroll down to the very end:

```
window.addEventListener(
    'load',
    init(null),
    false);
```

When the page loads it executes `init`:

```
function init(images) {

    canvas= document.getElementById('s');
    ctx= canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width= window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height=window.innerHeight;

    garden= new Garden();
    garden.initialize(canvas.width, canvas.height, 300);

    lerp(0,2000);

    time= new Date().getTime();
    interval = setInterval(_doit, 30);
}
```

The `init` function creates an instance of `Garden` (`garden = new Garden();`) and executes the `initialize` method of `garden`. It also calls the `_doit` function in intervals of 30 milliseconds.

```
initialize : function(width, height, size)  {
  this.width= width;
  this.height= height;
  this.grass= [];

  for(var i=0; i<size; i++ ) {
    var g= new Grass();
    g.initialize(
        width,
        height,
        50,      // min grass height 
        height*2/3, // max grass height
        20,     // grass max initial random angle 
        40      // max random angle for animation 
        );
    this.grass.push(g);
  }

  this.stars= [];
  for( i=0; i<this.num_stars; i++ )  {
    this.stars.push( Math.floor( Math.random()*(width-10)+5  ) );
    this.stars.push( Math.floor( Math.random()*(height-10)+5 ) );
  }
},
```

The `initialize` method of `garden` then creates some instances of `Grass`, calls their `initialize` methods and stores them in an array.

```
function _doit()    {

  ctx.fillStyle= gradient;
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  var ntime= new Date().getTime();
  var elapsed= ntime-time;
  garden.paint( ctx, elapsed );

  // lerp.
  if ( elapsed>nextLerpTime ) {
    lerpindex= Math.floor((elapsed-nextLerpTime)/nextLerpTime);
    if ( (elapsed-nextLerpTime)%nextLerpTime<lerpTime ) {
      lerp( (elapsed-nextLerpTime)%nextLerpTime, lerpTime );
    }
  }

}
```

The `_doit` function calls the `paint` function of `garden`, and the `paint` function of `garden` calls the `paint` function of each grass.

---

So here there are two constructors:

1. `Grass`
2. `Garden`

Here are the two prototypes:

1. `Grass.prototype`
2. `Garden.prototype`

Inside the `init` function we create a single instance of `Garden` (that's one object):

```
var garden= new Garden();
```

Inside the `initialize` method of `garden` we create multiple instances of `Grass`:

```
var g= new Grass();
```

That's it.

Comment: Very nice, I like how you used the term constructor to indicate a function creating an object and _not_ a function using the `new` keyword.

Comment: In JavaScript, it's best **not** to call a function a constructor if you don't call it via `new`. "Builder" (or less frequently "creator") is a better term, because the specification gives the term "constructor" a specific meaning.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I wouldn't give it any special label at all. I just used the term "constructor" for the sake of explanation. Personally, I prefer using the __prototypal pattern of prototypal inheritance__ over the __constructor pattern of prototypal inheritance__ that most people use. That's one of the things about JavaScript that I don't like: the constructor pattern. It's problematic and hides true the prototypal pattern. You should read my blog post if you haven't. I tried to explain prototypal inheritance as best as I could. Apparently Eric Elliot from Adobe thought it was a great article. =)

Comment: @AaditMShah: I understand what you're doing, I'm just saying that it's best not to confuse matters by calling it a "constructor," because the language (via its spec) gives that term a *specific* (and different) meaning. I have no problem at all with the approach. One of the things I love about JS is that it's so flexible, you can take a more traditional prototypical approach to creating objects. The language can be used in multiple ways, which I love about it.

Comment: @AaditMShah:hii,i liked your answer and went through your blog.now i can say that i do understand a little about prototypes,constructor and objects.the link below is an example of prototypical approach that you mentioned.I think that is the proper standard for writing any code.can you just tell me which are the constructors,prototypes and objects in that code,i promise i wont trouble u any more.
http://cssdeck.com/labs/4ksohwya
(things to look out for--function paint,initialize and the way they are called-can you just brief me about that)

Comment: @jayeshjain - Thank you. I saw the link you posted. Wow, that's an amazing animation. Anyway, I updated my answer to point out the constructors, prototypes and objects and to explained how the `initialize` and `paint` methods are called. Hope that helps.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I understand your point of view, but I doubt people will get confused. Whether you call it a constructor, a builder or a creator in the end you have to understand prototypal inheritance. As long as you write legible code it doesn't matter.

Comment: @AaditMShah:You are 20,i can`t believe it,you are WOW!!!

Correct me if i am wrong,
1)---the instances that have been created--can i say that garden.initialize(canvas.width, canvas.height, 300); is constructor declaration just like function declaration ?so where is it defined..is it the instance that was created?

2)---if you see the first few lines of code,
Grass = function() {
        return this;
    };
there is no var mentioned,how is possible that its not showing any error as there is no var grass=0; defined prior to this?and if I am not wrong that is an object

3)---when to use this?

Comment: @AaditMShah:
var g= new Grass();
is g a constructor in this?

Comment: @jayeshjain Constructors are functions which create objects. The example you cited has only two constructors - `Grass` and `Garden`. In JavaScript any function can be used as a constructor by adding `new` before the function call. Hence `var g = new Grass` calls the function `Grass` as a constructor and returns an object which is stored in `g`. This object `g` inherits all the properties of `Grass.prototype` which is the prototype of `g`. The `initialize` function is a property of the prototype and is hence inherited. It's not a constructor. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743

Comment: @AaditMShah:and suppose if i dont wanna use constructor,and using only prototype,would it be possible to create instances and inherit the properties?
i guess there create.object would come in to play?

Comment: @jayeshjain - Yes, indeed. That is the way I prefer creating objects. Say I have an object for a circle as follows: `var circle = { radius: 5, area: function () { return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius; } };`. Now I can use `circle.area()` to calculate the area of the circle. However if I want to create another circle I just need to extend this circle. We can use a function for this: `function createCircle(radius) { var newCircle = Object.create(circle); newCircle.radius = radius; return newCircle; }`. Now I can create as many circles as I want like this: `var ball = createCirlce(10);`. =)

Comment: @AaditMShah:Duniya Gol hai buddy!!!thx a ton man,but dont mind if i trouble u some more times!!!

Comment: @AaditMShah:why is the constructor grass enclosed in (function() {-----if u see it right at the beginning

Comment: @AaditMShah:right or wrong!!!
grass.prototype={a:1,b:2} is basically constructor.prototype={a:1,b:2}

Comment: @jayeshjain - The constructor is enclosed in what's called an IIFE - an [immediately invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/ "Ben Alman &raquo; Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)"). It' used to encapsulate private state. Yes, `Grass` (with a capital G) is a constructor and every function has a prototype. Hence `Grass.prototype` is kind of like `constructor.prototype`. Note however that you could also have another function called `constructor`.

Answer (score 12):

Okay, a whirlwind tour:

### Objects

An object is a thing that has *properties*. Properties have names and values. The names are always strings (although we can write them without quotes most of the time), and the values can be anything JavaScript supports: Numbers, strings, booleans, null, undefined, or references to objects.

So:

```
var a = {
    propertyName: "property value"
};
```

`a` is a variable referring to an object, which has a property named `propertyName`, whose value is the string `"property value"`.

### Prototypes

An object (say, `obj`) can have another object (say, `p`) "behind" it, where `p` lends `obj` its properties unless `obj` has its own property with a given name. `p` is the *prototype* object of `obj`. This is easiest to understand with an example:

```
// Let's create an object `p` with a couple of properties, `x` and `y`
// This syntax is called an "object initializer" (aka "object literal")
var p = {
    x: "x on p",
    y: "y on p"
};

// Now, we'll create a new object, `obj`, using `p` as its prototype
var obj = Object.create(p);

// And that means if we ask `obj` for a property called `x`, since it doesn't
// have its **own** `x`, it asks `p` for it. (And the same with `y`)
console.log(obj.x); // "x on p"
console.log(obj.y); // "y on p"

// But we can give `obj` its *own* `x` instead if we want
obj.x = "x on obj";
console.log(obj.x); // "x on obj"
console.log(obj.y); // "y on p"

// Doing that to `obj` had no effect on `p`
console.log(p.x); // "x on p"
console.log(p.y); // "y on p"
```

A very, very important aspect of prototypes is that the connection between the objects is **live**. So if `obj` doesn't have a `y` property, every time we ask `obj` for `y` it goes and asks `p`. And so if we change `p`'s value for `y`, that change shows up if we ask `obj` for it:

```
var p = {
    x: "x on p",
    y: "y on p"
};

var obj = Object.create(p);

console.log(obj.y); // "y on p"

p.y = "updated y on p";

console.log(obj.y); // "updated y on p"
```

This **live** connection is a vital thing. So again, think of it like this: We *ask* `obj` for the property `y`, and `obj` says "I don't have my own, so I'll go ask `p` for it and give you that."

Note: The `Object.create` function I've been using to create `obj` is new as ECMAScript5 (the spec update from a couple of years ago). We'll come back to another way to given an object a prototype further down.

The prototype for an object is currently always set when the object is created, and cannot be changed (I couldn't swap in a `q` instead of `p` above after creating `obj`). Above I'm using `Object.create` to do it (and below we'll talk about constructor functions). Until ECMAScript5 (ES5), there was no standard way to get the prototype of an object. ES5 gives us a way to do it now, called `Object.getPrototypeOf`, but still doesn't offer a way to change it. The next version, ES6, will take things a bit further.

### Functions

Functions are units of code that do things. Functions are also objects, and so they can have properties, although in practice it's relatively rare to use properties on functions (other than `call` and `apply`, which we don't need to talk about here).

You can *declare* a function:

```
function foo() {
}
```

...or you can create one with an *expression*:

```
// An anonymous -- unnamed -- function assigned to variable `foo`
var foo = function() {
};

// A function named `f` assigned to variable `foo`
var foo = function f() {
};
```

Declarations and expressions are different. Function declarations are evaluated before any step-by-step code in the same scope is performed. Function expressions are evaluated as they're encountered in the step-by-step code, like all other expressions. (People sometime call this "hoisting" because it means that in effect, even if a function declaration is at the bottom of a scope, it happens as though it had been lifted -- hoisted -- to the top.)

Functions can have arguments:

```
// `a` and `b` are arguments
function sum(a, b) {
    console.log(a + b);
}
```

And they can have return values:

```
function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
console.log(sum(1, 2)); // "3"
```

If a function doesn't return something else, the result of calling the function is the value `undefined`.

### Methods

JavaScript doesn't have methods. It only has functions — but that's all it really needs. But if you have a function assigned to an object property, and you call that function as part of an expression retrieving the property from the object, then something happens that makes JavaScript **seem** to have methods: The `this` keyword refers to that object within the function call. Again, an example works wonders:

```
// A blank object
var obj = {};

// Lets put a function on it as a property
obj.foo = function() {
    console.log("this is obj? " + this === obj);
};

// Let's call that function
obj.foo(); // "this is obj? true"
```

More on my blog:

- [*Mythical Methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

### Constructors

Constructor functions are used with the `new` keyword, and they're one of the ways you give an object a prototype. When you call a function via `new`, a new object is created, and assigned a prototype from the function's `prototype` property:

```
function Foo() {
}
Foo.prototype.x = "x on Foo.prototype";

var obj = new Foo();
console.log(obj.x); // "x on Foo.prototype"
```

Every function automatically has a `prototype` property, even though of course we don't use the vast majority of functions as constructors.

An important thing to note here: The `prototype` property of a function is just a boring old property. It isn't the prototype of any object until/unless that function is called via the `new` operator. The `new` operator *uses* the `prototype` property of the function to set the prototype of the new object when you call the function via `new`, but that's all.

It's worth mentioning that until ES5, constructor functions like the above were the only way you could create an object with a given prototype. But with ES5, we got `Object.create`, which opened up more patterns for how to use JavaScript. (It was always possible to create your own `Object.create`, by using a temporary function, and in fact that's exactly what some people did.) Some people don't like using the `new` keyword and the `prototype` property, they prefer to use a "builder" pattern where you just call a function and get back an object. JavaScript is so flexible that you can do that.

---

### More to Explore

- I write about JavaScript on my blog: [Nifty Snippets - `javascript` label](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/search/label/javascript)
- The [Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) has excellent JavaScript information
- There is, of course, the specification — it's the best source for the actual nitty-gritty detail, but it's very hard reading :-)

Comment: Very high quality and nice answer. The only thing I think is missing here is more references to places like MDN, and the specification.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am too late, but here would be my 2 cents:

**Prototype:**

```
String.prototype.x = "yahoo"
```

now every instance of **String** will have the property **x**.

So be it `(new String()).x` or `"".x` both have the value equal to *yahoo*

Hence it's like extending a predefined class.

---

**Objects**

Everything in JavaScript, except the other primitive types, is an object.

An object is a collection of name-value pairs, nothing more, nothing less.

```
{"a": 0, "b" : 1}
```

Even an **Array** is an object in JS with some additional properties & methods.

---

**Functions & Methods**

Here is a function :

```
function a() { };
```

Now let's give it the status of a method of an **Array**:

```
Array.prototype.a = a;
```

---

**Constructor:**

```
new String()
```

gets the implementation of String from : `String.constructor`

Similarly the code you write in any function goes into this very function.

Comment: *"gets the implementation of `String` from : `String.constructor`"* No, it doesn't, it gets it from `String` and `String.prototype`. Also, I would **strongly** recommend not using extending native types as your example for how prototypes work.

Comment: @loxxy:dont underestimate your self,your expalnation is definately more than 2 cents,nice,short and simple!!!

Answer (score -4):

JavaScript is the scripting language used in web applications to make the web pages dynamic. This language allows to handle user actions by handling events on the elements displayed on the page.... Also it is used to modify the content on the web page based on the condition...

The method (or) function is the programming construct used in javascript for specifying the logic. You will put the your required logic in a  method and you will invoke it from the web page upon any event...

There are no constructors in javascript...

There will be implicit and user defined objects in javascript... Implicit objects include Date, Array etc...

This is just a basic abstract.. you need to follow either websites (or) books to know much more about javascript