# How to change the constructor of an object?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I am diving deeper into Javascript, and learning how constructor methods work.

In the code below, I would expect that I would be able to overwrite the constructor of an object, so that newly created instances would use the new constructor. However, I can't seem to make new instances use a new constructor.

Any insight as to what is going on would be greatly appreciated!

```
function constructorQuestion() {
    alert("this is the original constructor");
};

c = new constructorQuestion();
constructorQuestion.constructor = function() { alert("new constructor");}
howComeConstructorHasNotChanged = new constructorQuestion();
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hammerbrostime/6nxSW/1/

Comment: Forgot to add the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hammerbrostime/6nxSW/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `constructor` is a property of the `prototype` of the function, not the function itself. Do:

```
constructorQuestion.prototype.constructor = function() {
    alert("new constructor");
}
```

For more information see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743

---

BTW, if you expect the code `howComeConstructorHasNotChanged = new constructorQuestion();` to alert `"new constructor"` that won't happen. This is because you're not calling the new constructor, you're calling the old one. What you want is:

```
howComeConstructorHasNotChanged = new constructorQuestion.prototype.constructor;
```

Changing the `constructor` property doesn't magically change the constructor.

What you really want is:

```
function constructorQuestion() {
    alert("this is the original constructor");
};

c = new constructorQuestion();

function newConstructor() {
    alert("new constructor");
}

newConstructor.prototype = constructorQuestion.prototype;

howComeConstructorHasNotChanged = new newConstructor();
```

This will work. See: http://jsfiddle.net/GMFLv/1/

Comment: Just tried it out, but getting the same behavior as in my original post. Here is the fiddle with your changes: http://jsfiddle.net/hammerbrostime/GMFLv/

Comment: @hammerbrostime - You're doing it wrong. Changing the `constructor` property doesn't change the constructor. Do this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/GMFLv/1/

Comment: Aadit, thanks for the detailed response. Is it necessary to create a new object? I'd like to see if we can change the constructor for the original constructorQuestion object, so that we could call new constructorQuestion().

Comment: @hammerbrostime - No, this is the only way to achieve what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be same to create new object with same prototype like this:

```
function newClass(){
    alert('new class with same prototype');
}

newClass.prototype = constructorQuestion.prototype;
```