# javascript checking object prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is there any difference between following pieces of code:

```
inst instanceof Constr
```

and

```
inst.__proto__ === Constr.prototype
```

for example:

```
var xyz = {}
xyz instanceof Object
```

and

```
xyz.__proto__ === Object.prototype
```

? If so, what is the difference, which one is the preferred?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__proto__` isn't part of the ECMAScript 5 specification, and you have no guarantee of future support. The standard ways to access the prototype of an object are to access the prototype of the constructor or, better, [Object.getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) (but this doesn't work on IE8).

[instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) checks the prototype of the constructor but also *"tests presence of constructor.prototype in object prototype chain."*.

If your goal is to check if an object is an instance of a specific class, and it's OK for you if it's not a direct instance, then you should use the `instanceof` operator : it's really just made for that.

Answer (score 2):

There are two differences. As others have mentioned before `instanceof` is recursive. You can implement your own version of `instanceof` as follows:

```
function instanceOf(obj, func) {
    return Object.isPrototypeOf.call(func.prototype, obj);
}
```

This function depends upon the availability of the [`Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf) function.

The second difference is only for browsers. As mentioned in the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743) the actual implementation of `instanceof` is as follows in browsers:

```
function instanceOf(obj, func) {
    var prototype = func.prototype;

    while (obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)) { //traverse the prototype chain
        if (typeof object === "xml")           //workaround for XML objects
            return prototype === XML.prototype;
        if (obj === prototype) return true;    //object is instanceof constructor
    }

    return false; //object is not instanceof constructor
}
```

That's all. For more information see the documentation of `instanceof`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#Determining_instance_relationships

Comment: By "actual implementation in browsers" you again mean abstract pseudo code that no actual implementation would use in actually implementing it :P

Comment: @Esailija I wouldn't actually bother looking up the code for `instanceof` in the V8 engine now, would I? =P

Answer (score 1):

Instanceof checks further

```
var GrandParent=function(){};
var Parent = function(){}
Parent.prototype=new GrandParent()
var Child = function(){};
Child.prototype=new Parent()

var c=new Child();
console.log(c instanceof GrandParent);//true
console.log(c.__proto__ === GrandParent);//false
```

Answer (score 1):

There actually is a third way, that looks a lot like the non-standard `__proto__` examples:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf([]) === Array.prototype
```

Be weary:

```
console.log([] instanceof Object);//ture
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf([]) === Object.prototype);//false
```

Basically, the `instanceof` operator checks the entire prototype-chain, the other methods don't