# Unable to understand <x>.prototype.constructor?

Tags: javascript

I have two classes `Car` and `Maruti`. When i use inheritance by assigning the prototype of `Maruti` to new `Car` object. Why do i have to set the `Maruti.prototype.constructor` to `Maruti`. Shown in the code below.

```
function Car(){
}

function Maruti(){
}

Maruti.prototype = new Car()
Maruti.prototype.constructor = Maruti
```

Unable to understand the last line of the code. Can someone explain in detail?

Comment: Ad the title: are you asking us whether you are unable to understand <x>.prototype.constructor? Problably yes, otherwise you wouldn't be asking.

Comment: Constructor can be used in the following way: `Person.prototype.haveChild=function(){return new this.constructor()}` That should return a new Person but if you have Person inherit from some other object you just overwritten the Person.prototpe.constructor so it points to the wrong constructor. You may never use constructor and a lot of example code will just ignore it (like the ever posted `Maruti.prototype = Object.create(Car.prototype)`) But if you (or someone extending or using your code) want to use it later then you need to fix it.

Comment: It's better not to call the "Parent" constructor code when you set up inheritance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711 under `Setting prototype without calling the constructor`

Answer (score 0):

If `Maruti` inherit `Car` using `Maruti.prototype = new Car()`, you need to reset the constructor property for the class `Maruti` using `Maruti.prototype.constructor=Maruti;`, otherwise instances of `Maruti` would have a constructor of `Car`.

Answer (score 0):

Before you set `Maruti.prototype = new Car` the `prototype` of `Maruti` has only one property, `constructor`, which is set to `Maruti` itself:

```
function Car() {}

function Maruti(){}

console.log(Maruti.prototype); // logs the following
                               // {
                               //     constructor: Maruti
                               // }

Maruti.prototype = new Car;
Maruti.prototype.constructor = Maruti;
```

After you set the `prototype` of `Maruti` to `new Car` the `constructor` property is lost (because its not the same object). Instead `Maruti.prototype.constructor` will now be `Car` (because its inherited from `Car.prototype`). Hence we set the `constructor` property to `Maruti` again.

For a more visual explanation take a look at the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743

Answer (score 0):

Given this,

```
function Car(){
}
```

and that the `constructor` property is a property of the functions prototype

Now, if you look up the constructor of a new `Car` instance

`new Car().constructor === Car`

You see it is `Car`, then you are setting

```
function Maruti(){
}
Maruti.prototype = new Car();
```

Remember that `new Car().constructor === Car`?,
as such is now, `Maruti.prototype.constructor === Car`, hence shadowed down to the `Maruti` instance, overriding the original `Maruti.prototype.constructor`

So, if you create a new Instance of `Maruti` and lookup the constructor

`new Maruti().constructor === Car`

You see it is `Car`,
though `new Maruti()` is constructed by `Maruti` and not by `Car`