# Why does JavaScript's instanceof operator say that an object is not an Object?

Tags: javascript, instanceof

For some reason I came across a case where Chrome's V8 seems to think that an object is not actually an Object. I can't reproduce this easily but basically I have this code segment:

```
if (!(obj instanceof Object)) {
    console.log(obj);
}
```

And yet chrome's console shows that it is in fact an Object... Does anyone know what could possibly cause this? How can I reproduce this?

WHen I use the typeof operator, it correctly identifies it as an object.

Comment: What does `console.log(obj)` show?

Comment: can you paste `obj` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be from a different `window` (e.g. an iframe), which has an own `Object` constructor

```
var obj = frame.contentWindow.obj;
console.log(obj instanceof Object); // false
console.log(obj instanceof frame.contentWindow.Object); // true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JnfPR/1/

Also note that there is a variety of objects in JS, including "Array objects", "RegExp objects", "Function objects", ... and "Object objects". The `typeof` operator is not very helpful there. It can only distinguish between Function objects and other objects.

Comment: I think that explains it - The project does involve iframes... Very unusual issue. Thanks for that explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you override `__proto__`. For example:

```
var myObj = { __proto__: null };

(myObject instanceof Object) === false;
```

This is due to how `instanceof` works – it basically walks up the prototype chain looking for the constructor you passed to it. More information about `instanceof` is available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

Answer (score 1):

An object need not be an instance of `Object` in JavaScript. For example:

```
var obj = Object.create(null);
console.log(obj instanceof Object); // false
console.log(typeof obj);            // object
```

The reason for this is because of the way `instanceof` is implemented. See the following answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743

Answer (score 0):

> The instanceof operator tests whether an object has in its prototype
>   chain the prototype property of a constructor.

You can check [Mozilla's developer site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

Basically the `instanceof` operator evaulates to true if the object inherits from the classe's prototype, so for example:

```
 var a = new Animal():
```

Here `a is instance of Animal` since `a` inherits from `Animal.prototype`

Comment: While this answer does correctly explain `instanceof` behavior, it does not explain how an object could be missing `Object.prototype` from its prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

[Typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) gives you the type of an object (in this case "object") and [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) tests the prototype chain.

```
o={};
o instanceof Object //is true
typeof o // "object" 
typeof(o.constructor.prototype)==="object" // is true
```

So in your case, the error has to be in the `obj`.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely dealing with a null value:

```
console.log(null instanceof Object);//false
console.log(typeof(null));// object
```

Or as Pumbaa80 commented; you got the object from an Iframe so it's constructor isn't the same Object as in the main window therefor instanceof Object is false but the variable does have an object value.