# What are the downsides of defining functions on prototype this way?

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

Usually people write code like this:

```
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
}
```

However I was trying to come up with a way to define a function on a prototype without separating the function definition with the constructor.  Here is what I got:

```
Object.prototype.method = function(name, func) {
  if (typeof(this.constructor.prototype[name]) === 'undefined') {
    this.constructor.prototype[name] = func
  }
}
```

This allows you to do something like:

```
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;

  this.method('move', function(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
  })
}
```

And also no matter how many times you create a shape, the function will only be defined once.

I'm aware that augmenting `Object.prototype` isn't considered a good practice.  But other than that are there any downsides with this approach?

EDIT:

Johan brought up a good point; I should have made `method` not enumerable.  Here is the revised version:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'method', {
    value: function(name, func) {
        if (typeof(this.constructor.prototype[name]) === 'undefined') {
            this.constructor.prototype[name] = func
        }
    },
    enumerable: false
})
```

Comment: This will lead to bugs that are hard to track down.

Comment: Take a look at my [`augment`](https://github.com/javascript/augment) method. I think you would find it much more appealing.

Comment: @AaditMShah dude that's literally the cleverest code I've seen in while.  I will definitely use it in my projects.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here's a great answer on SO for javascript inheritance, with 420 upvotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's actually compare both the ways and see which one is faster: http://jsperf.com/traditional-oop-vs-derek-s-oop-variant

As you can see your method is much slower than the traditional method. The reasons are:

1. Your constructor is doing more stuff than required. Hence if you create multiple instances then the extra cost of creating an instance adds up.
2. As @Alxandr mentioned you're creating a new anonymous function for `method` every time you create a new instance for no good reason. It'll only be useful once after which it'll be a waste of processing power.
3. You're calling a function to check whether the `prototype` of the constructor has a given method or not, and to add the method to the `prototype` if it doesn't. This seems unnecessary. You don't need to create a function to do this for you. IMHO the function call is just additional overhead.

Since you asked for criticism:

> I'm aware that augmenting `Object.prototype` isn't considered a good practice. But other than that are there any downsides with this approach?

Beside being terribly slow your approach also suffers from:

1. Being difficult to understand. You may find this approach intuitive. However a person reading your code would surely wonder what the function `this.method` does. They would need to read the definition of `Object.prototype.method` to fully comprehend your code.
2. Being unintuitive. As I mentioned before it makes no sense to be defining `prototype` properties inside the constructor. It'll only be needed once after which it'll just become additional baggage. It's best to keep the constructor logic and the `prototype` properties separate.
3. It may lead to unexpected behavior. As @basilikum pointed out if you never call the constructor then the `prototype` properties will never be set. This may lead to problems when you attempt to access a property on the `prototype`. For example, when inheriting properties from the `prototype` no properties will be inherited until the base constructor is called.

I believe your goal is to encapsulate both the constructor and the `prototype` properties into a single entity:

> However I was trying to come up with a way to define a function on a prototype without separating the function definition with the constructor.

Is there an easy way to do this? Let's see, JavaScript is a [prototypal object oriented language](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/). Hence we should focus more on the [`prototype` instead of the constructor](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/#constructors_vs_prototypes).

[image]

The above diagram was taken from the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743

This diagram shows us:

1. Every constructor has a property called `prototype` which points to the prototype object of the constructor function.
2. Every prototype has a property called `constructor` which points to the constructor function of the prototype object.
3. We create an instance from a constructor function. However the instance actually inherits from the `prototype`, not the constructor.

This is very useful information. Traditionally we've always created a constructor function first and then we've set its `prototype` properties. However this information shows us that we may create a prototype object first and then define the `constructor` property on it instead.

For example, traditionally we may write:

```
function Shape() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}

Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
};
```

However using our newfound knowledge we may write the same thing as:

```
var shape = {
    constructor: function () {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    },
    move: function (x, y) {
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
    }
};
```

The information contained in both these examples is the same. However we need a little additional scaffolding to make the second example work. In particular we need to do:

```
var Shape = shape.constructor;
Shape.prototype = shape;
```

This is not a big issue. We simply create a function to do this for us:

```
function defclass(prototype) {
    var constructor = prototype.constructor;
    constructor.prototype = prototype;
    return constructor;
}
```

Now we can define `Shape` as follows:

```
var Shape = defclass({
    constructor: function () {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    },
    move: function (x, y) {
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
    }
});
```

As you can see encapsulation is easy to achieve in JavaScript. All you need to do is think sideways. Inheritance however is a different issue. You need to do a [little more work](https://github.com/javascript/augment) to achieve inheritance.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Ooo. I like this solution. And kudos for "thinking sideways". I'm going to start telling people to do that ^^.

Answer (score 3):

First off, you state that "the function will only be defined once", however, this is not true AFAIK. Every time you construct a new `Shape`, the anonymous function

```
function(x,y) { this.x += x; this.y += y }
```

get's redefined (unless the compiler/interpreter is smart enough to optimize this away as it isn't used). It then get's passed to the method `Object.prototype.method`, which chooses to ignore it (becuase the method was already defined), and is simply left in memory to be garbage-collected. Running this in a loop (if the compiler/interpreter isn't able to optimize it away), would result in a lot of functions being created for no good reason.

Also, as Johan stated, littering in `Object.prototype` may cause other code to stop working because suddenly `for(x in anything)` will show your new function `method`.

If you would like to "group" the declaration of the constructor, and it's methods together, you could rather create something like this:

```
function mangle(ctor, methods) {
    for(x in methods) {
        if(methods.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
            ctor.prototype[x] = methods[x];
        }
    }
    return ctor;
}
```

which you'd then call like this:

```
var Shape = mangle(function() {
    // moved default-values to prototype
    // so they don't have to be created
    // if they aren't set to something
    // else than the default.
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    move: function(x, y) {
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
    }
});
```

Or you could just stick to the normal design, or use a "class"-providing library like Prototype or MooTools. There are a lot of options to choose from.

Comment: Good catch on saying that the anonymous function might be reevaluated every time.  Can someone verify this?  Exactly what would the cost be?

Comment: Also, the `mangle` method you suggest isn't ideal, since you can't make use of the closure inside the constructor.  My `method`, however, allows you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Alxandr already said the most, but I'd like to point out another downside of your method.

The property `move` will only be there if you call the constructor at least once. This can be bad when it comes to inheritance. Take this for example:

```
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;

  this.method(this, 'move', function(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
  });
}
function Triangle() {
}

Triangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);

var t = new Triangle();
t.move(); //gives you an error because move is not defined
```

As you see, you have never called the constructor of `Shape` and therefor `move` isn't there yet. Normally you would call the `Shape` constructor inside of the `Triangle` constructor and you code would work fine, but there might be situation where you don't want to do this.

So I would advice to just stick to the original pattern. It is actually not that ugly when you get used to it.

Comment: I agree, but would also like to point out that using the "old school" (ie. before `Object.create`) way of "inheritance", you'd do `Triangle.prototype = new Shape()`, which would solve that particular problem. Still, I'm not defending the `method`-method, just saying that this exact downside is "fixable" of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

If you, or someone in the future trying loop over an `object` that is extended, the results might be unpredictable and break since the `object` now contains unknown properties. A little unforeseen gotcha!