# Confuse about prototype inheritance in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I want to achieve a extend method on a constructor function, and use it to initialize an instance, like:

```
var view_instance = View.extend()
```

so I tried this:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {

    function View(size, color) {
        this.size = size;
        this.color = color;
    };

    View.prototype = {
        show: function () {
            console.log("This is view show");
        }
    }

    View.extend = function (props) {
        var tmp = new this("12", "red");
        console.log(this);
            console.log(tmp instanceof this) //true
        console.log(tmp.prototype); //undefined!
        return tmp
    }

    return View;
})
```

in the above `extend` method, I initialize an instance through `new this()`, but I can't log its prototype, and I check the `this` is right.

So what's wrong with my code? Why the prototype disappear? How can I do it right?

Comment: Yo use [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) now

Comment: @aaronman: I try to achieve one by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. It does what it's supposed to do. The `prototype` property only exists on functions.

When you precede a function call with the `new` keyword JavaScript creates an object which inherits from the `prototype` of the constructor.

To put it in simple terms:

```
function F() {}                                        // we have a constructor
var o = new F;                                         // we create an instance
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(o) === F.prototype); // o inherits from
                                                       // F.prototype
```

Objects in JavaScript inherit from other objects via delegation. This means say we try to access a property on the object `o` which we saw above:

1. JavaScript will first try to find the property on `o` itself.
2. If it can't find the property on `o` then it will try to find it on `Object.getPrototypeOf(o)` (or to put it more succinctly `o.__proto__`). The prototype of `o` is `F.prototype`.
3. If it can't find the property on `F.prototype` then it will try to find it on `F.prototype.__proto__` which is `Object.prototype`.
4. If it can't find the property on `Object.prototype` then it will give up because `Object.prototype.__proto__` is `null`.

That is prototypal inheritance for you in a nutshell.

The reason your code logs `undefined` for `tmp.prototype` is because `tmp` doesn't have any property called `prototype`. Only functions have a `prototype` property. Try this instead:

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(tmp));
```

The above is the same as the following. However the `__proto__` property of objects is deprecated. Use it at your own risk:

```
console.log(tmp.__proto__);
```

If you want to learn more about inheritance then read the following articles:

1. [Aadit M Shah | Why Prototypal Inheritance Matters](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/)
2. [JavaScript inheritance and the constructor property - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743)

Answer (score 1):

`tmp.constructor.prototype` is what you want. `o.__proto__` is just a shortcut for `o.constructor.prototype` and [it's non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fproto).

[EDIT]

You can see the figure in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/what-is-the-difference-between-proto-and-prototype-in-javascript). It shows that `Foo.prototype.constructor` points to `Foo` itself. However, since you are overwriting the prototype of the constructor with the line `View.prototype = {...}`, `View.prototype.constructor` will be `function Object() { [native code] }` instead of `View` itself. **So a more accurate way would be assigning properties to the original prototype directly or overwriting it with the `constructor` property set manually:**

```
// Assign properties to the original prototype to prevent overwriting the `constructor` properties.
View.prototype.show = function() {};

// Or set the constructor manually.
View.prototype = {
  show: function() {},
  constructor: View
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `prototype` property belongs to constructors. The instances have a non-standard `__proto__` property pointing to the same object. So:

```
console.log(tmp.__proto__);
```

Or:

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(tmp));
```