# Can't access constructor after assigning prototype

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain why this is happening

```
function Human(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
var george = new Human('George');
alert(george.constructor === Human)
```

This shows true. whereas

```
var monkey = {
 hair: true,
 feeds: 'bananas',
 breathes: 'air'
};

function Human(name) {
 this.name = name;
}
Human.prototype = monkey;
var george = new Human('George');
alert(george.constructor === Human)
```

This shows false

Comment: the constructor property is not present on the object but on the prototype object. you ended up overwriting the prototype by doing this Human.prototype = monkey;

Comment: I marked this answer as a duplicate because the answer to the question is that the `constructor` property is present on the prototype of an object. When you are setting the prototype to some other object, you're effectively removing the `constructor` property, which is why `george.constructor === Human` evaluates to `false`. This is clearly explained in the answer to the question that this question is marked as a duplicate of.

Comment: @AaditMShah Ehm, these are not duplicates in any way shape or form.

Comment: @Lightness How are they not duplicates?

Comment: @Aadit They ask entirely different questions.

Comment: @Lightness I disagree. In the linked question the OP sets `b.prototype = new a()` and then asks why `(new b()).constructor` points to `a` and not `b`. This is essentially the same problem as described in this question. In this question the OP sets `Human.prototype = monkey` and then asks why `(new Human("George")).constructor === Human` is `false`. It seems to me that they are essentially the same question.

Comment: @AaditMShah: Nowhere in this question does the OP write `something.prototype = new somethingelse()`.

Comment: @Lightness Using an object literal is equivalent to calling `new Object`. My point is that the underlying problem is the same for both questions.

Comment: @AaditMShah: He's not assigning an object literal; he's assigning a reference to an existing object

Comment: @Lightness How does that affect the answer?

Comment: @AaditMShah: Whether it affects the answer is irrelevant. Your power to close questions as duplicates is about whether the _questions_ are duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

`constructor` is inherited from the `prototype`. Because you're changing the `Human`'s `prototype` to `monkey`, which is an `Object`, `george.constructor()` will now return `Object {}` instead of `Human {}`.

It's worth noting that `instanceof` will remain unchanged:

```
var george = new Human('George');
george.constructor === Human;        // true
george instanceof Human;             // true
```

```js
Human.prototype = {};
var george = new Human('George');
george.constructor === Human;        // false
george instanceof Human;             // true
```

Comment: A more in-depth explanation of why `george.constructor === Human` is `false` although `george instanceof Human` is `true`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743