# What does the top of the object graph look like in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

After the following code has been parsed by a JavaScript interpreter:

```
function F() {}
```

...is the following correct?

[image]

Comment: Read the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743

Answer (score 0):

After executing `function F() {}` the object layout is as follows:

```
+--------------------+
|        null        |
+--------------------+
          ^
          |              [[proto]]
[[proto]] |    +-----------------------------------+
          |    |                                   |
          |    v                                   |
+--------------------+  constructor  +----------+  |
|  Object.prototype  |-------------->|  Object  |  |
+--------------------+               +----------+  |
          ^                               |        |
          |              [[proto]]        |        |
[[proto]] |    +--------------------------+        |
          |    |                                   |
          |    v                                   |
+--------------------+  constructor  +----------+  |
|                    |-------------->|          |  |
| Function.prototype |   [[proto]]   | Function |  |
|                    |<--------------|          |  |
+--------------------+               +----------+  |
               ^                                   |
               |         [[proto]]                 |
               +--------------------------+        |
                                          |        |
                                          |        |
+--------------------+  constructor  +----------+  |
|    F.prototype     |-------------->|    F     |  |
+--------------------+               +----------+  |
          |                                        |
          |                                        |
          +----------------------------------------+
```

It's really simple:

1. All functions inherit from `Function.prototype` (i.e. the `[[proto]]` property of `Object`, `Function` and `F`, which are all functions, is `Function.prototype`).
2. The `constructor` property of each `Foo.prototype` is `Foo` itself (i.e. `Object.prototype.constructor` is `Object`, `Function.prototype.constructor` is `Function` & `F.prototype.constructor` is `F`).
3. `Object.prototype` inherits from `null` whereas `Function.prototype` and `F.prototype` inherit from `Object.prototype`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ended-up writing a blog post on my investigation into the top of the object graph in JavaScript.

https://medium.com/@benastontweet/javascript-inheritance-42d2216e9cf1