# JavaScript inheritance Object.create() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have:

Master object

```
function Fruit() {
    this.type = "fruit";
}
```

Sub-object:

```
function Bannana() {
    this.color = "yellow";
}
```

Inherit master properties

```
Bannana.prototype = Object.create( Fruit.prototype );

var myBanana = new Bannana();

console.log( myBanana.type );
```

Outputs: `undefined`. Why is this not displaying `"fruit"` as the outcome?

Comment: `Bannana.prototype =Object.create( new Fruit );` would probably do what you want

Comment: @dandavis: It does, but it's  not better than `Bannana.prototype = new Fruit();`

Comment: why do not go usual way, like: "public class Bannana extends Fruit"?

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev: i don't think that's the usual way since its not valid JS...

Comment: @dandavis: It's valid ES6/ES2015.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript inheritance and the constructor property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093057/javascript-inheritance-and-the-constructor-property)

Comment: ES6 is not a usual way of coding anything, at least not until it come out...

Comment: @dandavis: ES6 was officially released last week. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/ . If you are not already using the new syntax with all the tools out there, it's your loss ;)

Comment: that's good news, but Yevgeniy's code gives me a syntax error when i try it in chrome and firefox... any guess on when ES6 will be out in the wild to use in production? i would love to start using fat arrows...

Comment: @dandavis: Browsers will likely gradually implement new features. E.g. promises are already available in most browsers. You really should just use  [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and compile your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is this not displaying "fruit" as the outcome?

Because you are never setting `type` on the new object.

`type` isn't a property of `Fruit.prototype`, and all that `Bannana.prototype = Object.create( Fruit.prototype );` does is make the properties of `Fruit.prototype` available to each `Banana` instance.

`type` is set by the `Fruit` function. But if you look at your code, **nowhere** are you executing `Fruit`! The line `this.type = "fruit";` is never executed! The `type` property does not **magically** come to existence.

So  *in addition* to setting the prototype, you have to execute `Fruit`. You have to call the *parent* constructor (just like you do in other languages (and ES6 now) via `super`):

```
function Bannana() {
    Fruit.call(this); // equivalent to `super()` in other languages
    this.color = "yellow";
}
```

---

In the new JavaScript version (ES6/ES2015) you would use [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) instead:

```
class Banana extends Fruit {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.color = 'yellow;
    }
}
```

This does the same thing, but hides it behind the `class` syntax for ease of use.

Comment: as shown, is there any use of actually duping the proto since all the interesting "inherited" props are own properties ?

Comment: @dandavis: Not in this case but in general yes.

Comment: Nicely done Felix. Totally understand it better now! Thanks!

Comment: Ouch! That new JavaScript is distancing itself from prototypes and looks more class based.

Comment: @RobertRocha: Not really, it still creates the `Banana.prototype` object as you'd expect. It's mostly the looks.

Comment: @RobertRocha: afaik, the new JS doesn't add anything fundamental that ES5 lacks, it just makes it (a ton) prettier and more intuitive by providing syntactic sugar to look like older OOP langs.

Comment: @RobertRocha: Prototypes are just becoming an implementation detail, similar to how it is in Python.

Comment: @Felix Kling, Please, add "Bannana.prototype = new Fruit();" as a possible case in your answer, to have it explicit. Thanks.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev: I won't because I don't want to promote this style. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/218196

Answer (score 0):

This is so cool. If you go this way:

```
function Fruit() {
    this.type = "fruit";
}
function Bannana() {        
    this.color = "yellow";
}
Bannana.prototype =  new Fruit;
Bannana.prototype.type='flower';
var myBanana = new Bannana();
console.log( myBanana.type );
```

you will get a "**flower**", but if you go this way:

```
function Fruit() {
    this.type = "fruit";
}
function Bannana() {
    Fruit.call(this);
    this.color = "yellow";
}
Bannana.prototype.type='flower';
var myBanana = new Bannana();
console.log( myBanana.type );
```

You will get a "**fruit**";

I believe no explanation needed, right?

Comment: Don't know why `fruit` would be output. Have you created a question for this?

Answer (score -3):

You never put anything on the `Fruit` prototype object. Your constructor initializes the **instances**, not the prototype.

If you had:

```
Fruit.prototype.type = "fruit";
```

then your code would work as you expect.

Comment: I thought that `Bannana.prototype = Object.create( Fruit.prototype );` would cause inheritance of the master object properties that already have values.

Comment: @RobertRocha it would. Your code does not put any properties on the `Fruit` prototype. The code in your `Fruit` constructor, to be specific, does not do that.

Comment: @RobertRocha: JavaScript is less magical then you seem to think.

Comment: Sorry I am new to JavaScript and trying to learn the ropes of prototypes and how they work. In lots of code on MDN I see it use the `Object.create()` function when extending master objects. For some reason Bannana.prototype = new Fruit() seems to do the trick.

Comment: They also aren't calling the Fruit constructor from the Bannana constructor.