# JavaScript check if object has inherited property

Tags: javascript, inheritance

```
function Employee(name, dept) {
    this.name = name || "";
    this.dept  = dept || "general";
}

function WorkerBee(projs) {
    this.projects = projs || [];
}

WorkerBee.prototype = Object.create( Employee.prototype );

function Engineer(mach) {
    this.dept = "engineering";
    this.mach = mach || "";
}

Engineer.prototype = Object.create(WorkerBee.prototype);
var jane = new Engineer("belau");

console.log( 'projects' in jane );
```

Trying to check if `jane` inherited the `projects` property.

Outputs `false`. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Outputs `false`. Why?

Because `this.projects` is set inside `WorkerBee`, but that function is never executed.

This is the same issue as in your previous question: [JavaScript inheritance Object.create() not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30991020/218196)

Comment: Just realized that. What confused me was the use of `new` instead of `Object.create()`

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing for properties that are on the object itself (not a part of its prototype chain) you can use .hasOwnProperty():

```
if (x.hasOwnProperty('y')) { 
  // ......
}
```

Object or its prototype has a property:

You can use the in operator to test for properties that are inherited as well.

```
if ('y' in x) {
  // ......
}
```

Comment: While you are right, this doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: `x = "test"; try { if ('indexOf' in x) { console.log('it is correct answer'); }} catch (e) {console.log('it is wrong answer, actually'); }`